# Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(el) {
    if(el === 1) break;
});
```

How can I do this using the new `forEach` method in JavaScript? I've tried `return;`, `return false;` and `break`. `break` crashes and `return` does nothing but continue iteration.

Comment: It is worth noting that while `return` does indeed continue the iteration, it will skip any code that comes after it in the block.  Take this code for instance: ```[1,2,3].forEach(function(el) {
    if(el === 2) {
      console.log(`Match on 2!`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(el);
});``` .The `console.log(el);` will be skipped when 2 is matched.

Comment: There is a simple alternative:
for(const e of [1, 2, 3]){
    if(e == 2){
        break;
    }
    console.log(e)
}

Answer (score 2864, accepted):

There's no built-in ability to `break` in `forEach`. To interrupt execution you would have to throw an exception of some sort. eg.

```js
var BreakException = {};

try {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);
    if (el === 2) throw BreakException;
  });
} catch (e) {
  if (e !== BreakException) throw e;
}
```

JavaScript exceptions aren't terribly pretty. A traditional `for` loop might be more appropriate if you really need to `break` inside it.

### Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Instead, use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
[1, 2, 3].some(function(el) {
  console.log(el);
  return el === 2;
});
```

This works because `some` returns `true` as soon as any of the callbacks, executed in array order, return `true`, short-circuiting the execution of the rest.

`some`, its inverse [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (which will stop on a `return false`), and `forEach` are all ECMAScript Fifth Edition methods which will need to be added to the `Array.prototype` on browsers where they're missing.

### Use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
[1, 2, 3].every(v => {
  if (v > 2) {
    return false // "break"
  }
  console.log(v);
  return true // must return true if doesn't break
});
```

Comment: As many above have said, this is a technically interesting hack, but since it subverts and confuses the intended meaning of `some`/`every`, it is very much a hack. Considered harmful. Using an old-school `for` and/or prefiltering/slicing your array aren't as sexy, but they're better ideas.

Comment: You can also try to use ECMAScript2015 new for...of (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which would do exactly what you are looking for but the drawback is that this solution can cause issues for older browsers.

If you are looking for more generic solution that support more than just array, you could look at solution like this (https://github.com/nbouvrette/forEach)  one who can solve all your problems if you are willing to go this route.

Comment: when using es6, `for of` might be the best choice, especially if not dealing with arrays. check the other answer below.

Comment: The use of `Array#some` is really nice. Firstly its compatible with most browsers including ie9 and firefox 1.5 also works really well. My example use case will be to find the index in an array of ranges[a,b] where a number is between a lower boundary and upper boundary pair, test and return true when found. `for..of` would be the next best solution though only for newer browsers.

Comment: Exception handling should NEVER be used as control flow. PERIOD.

Comment: @frank I [wrote an esolang with only one loop construct: `forever`](https://gist.github.com/amcgregor/a816599dc9df860f75bd?ts=4#file-sample-clu-L67-L99). All other loop constructs are formed from `forever` and appropriate iterable exceptions, such as `ContinueIteration` and `StopIteration` (which `break` is a macro to raise).  On one hand: never.  On the other hand: always.  On the gripping hand: __sometimes__?  The "PERIOD" in your comment implies there may be a citation to back up your suggestion?

Comment: @frank it depends on the language. In Python it is perfectly acceptable to control flow with exception handling. In fact, `__next__()` raises `StopIteration` after generator exhaustion for that reason, as it is generally the best way to detect the end of a generator - it's way better than relying on magic return values. Python's ducktyping and EAFP patterns generally depend on exception handling as a flow control mechanic.

Comment: Using exception handling as control flow is bad juju. Use exceptions to notify of exceptions and handle them as unexpected results. They are not conditional operators.

Comment: This is a (very) old answer and flings bad practises (one simply does not use exceptions here). Keep scrolling down for better suggestions.

Comment: Upvoted for the use of "some". I would consider the exception version "bad practice" since it would be throwing an exception for a "normal" condition, thereby irritating those of us who like to debug with "halt on handled exceptions" turned on.

Comment: Yes, exception handling should not be used as a control flow ... except that `try-catch` is a construct that is *intended* to be used with more than just exception.  The only problem there is then the `BreakException` name.

JS's try/catch comes from a Lisp legacy, and the [WP page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#History) even says: "This was rapidly used not only for error raising, but **for non-local control flow**, and thus was augmented by two new keywords, `CATCH` and `THROW`"

Comment: I wouldn't use "some" since it was not the intention of the code (bad readability).

Comment: How is this an accepted solution!? Do NOT use exceptions as control flow!

Comment: @KarlAdler It probably depends on the task, but I'm leaning towards some/every being a hack in this case. Less readable because it's generally used for different purposes. find() might be a bit more readable. But generally it's best to find the element(s) and do with them what you need (after that).

Answer (score 841):

There is now an even better way to do this in ECMAScript2015 (aka ES6) using the new [for of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). For example, this code does not print the array elements after the number 5:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (const el of arr) {
  console.log(el);
  if (el === 5) {
    break;
  }
}
```

From the docs:

> Both **for...in** and **for...of** statements iterate over something. The main difference between them is in what they iterate over. The **for...in** statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in original insertion order. The **for...of** statement iterates over data that iterable object defines to be iterated over.

Need the index in the iteration? You can use [`Array.entries()`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/entries):

```
for (const [index, el] of arr.entries()) {
  if ( index === 5 ) break;
}
```

Comment: @superhero You can get the index of the element in a for...of loop, you just have to use `entries`.

    for (const [index, element] of someArray.entries()) {
      // ...
    }

Comment: isn't it recommended not to use for...in with arrays ?

Comment: @emostafa You are correct about for _in_ loops not being recommended for arrays, but this is approach actually uses a for **of** loop.

Comment: This is "for of", and this is a really clean solution... but this is also an ES6 feature, so just be aware that this will only work if your environment is setup for ES6.

Comment: I find myself using this solution a lot, and I use it for objects as well. With objects, you can do `Object.entries(myObject)` and then use it exactly like you use the `for..in` for the array. Note that JS arrays are basically objects under the hood: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html

Comment: How exactly does it answer the question?

Comment: A simple for loop is still faster than the _better_ way.

Answer (score 243):

You can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```
[1,2,3].every(function(el) {
    return !(el === 1);
});
```

ES6

```
[1,2,3].every( el => el !== 1 )
```

for old browser support use:

```
if (!Array.prototype.every)
{
  Array.prototype.every = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this &&
          !fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this))
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  };
}
```

more details [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_every.htm).

Comment: Nice and clean in ES6 now - `[1,2,3].every( el => el !== 1 )`

Comment: @Valdemar, But does `every` **guarantee** that calls are made in sequence?

Comment: @Pacerier, you can see the algorithm in the ES6 specification that the index `k` starts at 0 and is incremented by 1: [http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.every](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.every)

Comment: @XP1, Are all implementors required to do it that way?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, most popular implementations work properly.
If you are concerned about embedded implementations, usually it's Opera or webkit.
Method every calls callbackfn once for each element present in the array, **in ascending order**, until it finds one where callbackfn returns false. Also look at step 7. Let k be 0. and 8.e Increase k by 1.

Comment: Changes the intention of the code. Very bad.

Comment: @Cesar, thanks for replying, but could you please explain, why does it change intention? I thought the intention was to do something and exit forEach cycle in some moment.

Comment: @Valdemar_Rudolfovich the usage of "some" is finding if some items match some criteria, "every" is intended to find out if all the items in a set match a criteria. On the other hand breaking isn't always connected to a criteria but breaks some logic. Although the example given (if(el === 1)) might be implemented by "some", but I believe the question was about a general case.

Comment: @Cesar, thanks again for the explanation, I agree with you, that the "some" method might be better in a particular case when you are searching for one exact condition. But if you are inverting the condition or say that I want to check that none of the elements equals 1, then the "every" method might be used as well. The question was about breaking the loop, both of these methods are suitable there.

Comment: MDN also has a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#polyfill

Answer (score 139):

Quoting from the [MDN documentation of `Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is ***no way to stop or break*** a `forEach()` loop other than 
>   by throwing an exception. If you need such behaviour, the `.forEach()` method is the ***wrong tool***, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a boolean return value, you can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

For your code (in the question), as suggested by @bobince, use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead. It suits very well to your usecase.

> `Array.prototype.some()` executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value (a value that becomes true when converted to a `Boolean`). If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns true. Otherwise, `some()` returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

Comment: This is the correct answer. 'some' does exactly what a foreach/break would do. It loops until iteration n = true.

Comment: Sonar flags it, not using the returned value from array.some(). The logic is to use it only for looping.

Answer (score 119):

Unfortunately in this case it will be much better if you don't use `forEach`. 
Instead use a regular `for` loop and it will now work exactly as you would expect.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === 1){
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: It shocks me that the highest vote is the worst implementation possible, compared to the higher performing, less code, and better readability of this correct answer.  Throw exception... really?  Is the traditional for loop just not kewl enough?

Comment: @gdbj I agree with your statement and used this method, but what really shocks me is there is no way of exiting a forEach without these hacks, now that's bad design.

Comment: @gdbj I also agree, but the issue is more with Stack Overflow and its guidelines.  The question specifically asks for a solution to break out of an Array.forEach loop. The accepted answer does that... in an incredibly ugly way. Technically this answer is incorrect, even though it achieves the same goal in a tried and true fashion.

Answer (score 43):

From your code example, it looks like `Array.prototype.find` is what you are looking for: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
[1, 2, 3].find(function(el) {
    return el === 2;
}); // returns 2
```

Answer (score 28):

Consider to use `jquery`'s `each` method, since it allows to return false inside callback function:

```
$.each([{user: "barney", active: false}, {user: "fred", active: false}],function(e, i) { 
   if (i % 2) return false;
   console.log(e)
})
```

Lodash libraries also provides [`takeWhile`](https://lodash.com/docs#takeWhile) method that can be chained with map/reduce/fold etc:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'active': true }
];
 
_.takeWhile(users, function(o) { return !o.active; });
// => objects for ['barney', 'fred']
 
// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.takeWhile(users, { 'user': 'barney', 'active': false });
// => objects for ['barney']
 
// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.takeWhile(users, ['active', false]);
// => objects for ['barney', 'fred']
 
// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.takeWhile(users, 'active');
// => []
```

Comment: Good reason to use jQuery. forEach in native javascript is still lacking.

Comment: @AlexGrande jQuery's forEach and JavaScript's forEach are not compatible.

Comment: JavaScript is used in many places that jQuery is not an option.

Comment: The jQuery code using `each` is incorrect. It takes an array and a callback. It should rather be something like: `$.each(array,function(e, i) { 
   if (i % 2) return false;
   console.log(e)
});`

See: [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback)

Answer (score 21):

If you would like to use [Dean Edward's suggestion](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/07/enum/#comment105309) and throw the StopIteration error to break out of the loop without having to catch the error, you can use the following the function ([originally from here](http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/06/30/javascript-foreach-with-breaking/#comment-78)):

```
// Use a closure to prevent the global namespace from be polluted.
(function() {
  // Define StopIteration as part of the global scope if it
  // isn't already defined.
  if(typeof StopIteration == "undefined") {
    StopIteration = new Error("StopIteration");
  }

  // The original version of Array.prototype.forEach.
  var oldForEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

  // If forEach actually exists, define forEach so you can
  // break out of it by throwing StopIteration.  Allow
  // other errors will be thrown as normal.
  if(oldForEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function() {
      try {
        oldForEach.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0));
      }
      catch(e) {
        if(e !== StopIteration) {
          throw e;
        }
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

The above code will give you the ability to run code such as the following without having to do your own try-catch clauses:

```
// Show the contents until you get to "2".
[0,1,2,3,4].forEach(function(val) {
  if(val == 2)
    throw StopIteration;
  alert(val);
});
```

One important thing to remember is that this will only update the Array.prototype.forEach function if it already exists.  If it doesn't exist already, it will not modify the it.

Answer (score 18):

Short answer: use `for...break` for this or change your code to avoid breaking of `forEach`. Do not use `.some()` or `.every()` to emulate `for...break`. Rewrite your code to avoid `for...break` loop, or use `for...break`. Every time you use these methods as `for...break` alternative God kills kitten.

Long answer:

`.some()` and `.every()` both return `boolean` value, `.some()` returns `true` if there any element for which passed function returns `true`, every returns `false` if there any element for which passed function returns `false`. This is what that functions mean. Using functions for what they doesn't mean is much worse then using tables for layout instead of CSS, because it frustrates everybody who reads your code.

Also, the only possible way to use these methods as `for...break` alternative is to make side-effects (change some vars outside of `.some()` callback function), and this is not much different from `for...break`.

So, using `.some()` or `.every()` as `for...break` loop alternative isn't free of side effects, this isn't much cleaner then `for...break`, this is frustrating, so this isn't better.

You can always rewrite your code so that there will be no need in `for...break`. You can filter array using `.filter()`, you can split array using `.slice()` and so on, then use `.forEach()` or `.map()` for that part of array.

Comment: using .filter is actually the appropriate solution for a lot of use cases for breaking.

Comment: What about performance? Woudln't filter affect performance if used frequently?

Comment: Yes, the filter array prototype can get heavy.  I love it, but it could effect performance if it's overused.

Comment: @tfrascaroli use `for...break` loop if you need performance. `for` loop is the most performant iteration tool than `.forEach()`, `.any()`, `.map()`, `.filter()` etc.

Comment: Why is using a table for layout a bad thing if you intend to build a table? Actually, not using a table when needing a table is just like using some, every instead of breaking. The table thing has nothing to do with readability.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned before, you can't break `.forEach()`.

Here's a slightly more modern way of doing a foreach with ES6 Iterators. Allows you to get direct access to `index`/`value` when iterating.

```
const array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

for (const [index, val] of array.entries()) {
  console.log('item:', { index, val });
  if (index === 1) {
    console.log('break!');
    break;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
item: { index: 0, val: 'one' }
item: { index: 1, val: 'two' }
break!
```

#### Links

- [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)
- [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 8):

Another concept I came up with:

```js
function forEach(array, cb) {
  var shouldBreak;
  function _break() { shouldBreak = true; }
  for (var i = 0, bound = array.length; i < bound; ++i) {
    if (shouldBreak) { break; }
    cb(array[i], i, array, _break);
  }
}

// Usage

forEach(['a','b','c','d','e','f'], function (char, i, array, _break) {
  console.log(i, char);
  if (i === 2) { _break(); }
});
```

Comment: The syntax is similar to [NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock], Thanks!

Comment: @Drenai the signature is analogous to the native [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).  [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) existed long before this question was asked; the OP was looking for that behaviour using, the more functional, `forEach`.

Comment: @Drenai has now deleted their comment (but left the downvote) which mentioned that the signature of this solution is hard to remember and unnecessary when you can solve the problem with `for...in` and `break`.

Answer (score 7):

This is just something I came up with to solve the problem... I'm pretty sure it fixes the problem that the original asker had:

```
Array.prototype.each = function(callback){
    if(!callback) return false;
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
        if(callback(this[i], i) == false) break;
    }
};
```

And then you would call it by using:

```
var myarray = [1,2,3];
myarray.each(function(item, index){
    // do something with the item
    // if(item != somecondition) return false; 
});
```

Returning false inside the callback function will cause a break. Let me know if that doesn't actually work.

Comment: `=== false` might be better than `== false` so you don't have to explicitly return true (or a truthy value) to continue the loop, lest some control path doesn't return a value and the loop breaks unexpectedly.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to access your array after iteration you can bail out by setting the array's length to 0. If you do still need it after your iteration you could clone it using slice..

```
[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,244,3,5,2].forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
  if (index === 3) arr.length = 0;
});
```

Or with a clone:

```
var x = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,244,3,5,2];

x.slice().forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
  if (index === 3) arr.length = 0;
});
```

Which is a far better solution then throwing random errors in your code.

Comment: well done :)
but if there are some actions after assigning `array.length` to `0` they will apply in current iteration, so probably it's sometimes better to use `return` after such assigning

Comment: This is technically wrong.  forEach will still check for the existence of indices 4 through 10.  But because they don't exist anymore, nothing is executed for them.  However, if the array were to become repopulated prior to the completion of the checks, the callback would be called on the values of the remaining indices.

Answer (score 4):

Found this solution on another site. You can wrap the forEach in a try / catch scenario.

```
if(typeof StopIteration == "undefined") {
 StopIteration = new Error("StopIteration");
}

try {
  [1,2,3].forEach(function(el){
    alert(el);
    if(el === 1) throw StopIteration;
  });
} catch(error) { if(error != StopIteration) throw error; }
```

More details here: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/07/enum/

Comment: Don't use exceptions as a control flow statements. Use it for handling unexpected results.

Answer (score 4):

This is a for loop, but maintains the object reference in the loop just like a forEach() but you can break out.

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
for (var i = 0, el; el = arr[i]; i++) {
    if(el === 1) break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try with "find" :

```
var myCategories = [
 {category: "start", name: "Start", color: "#AC193D"},
 {category: "action", name: "Action", color: "#8C0095"},
 {category: "exit", name: "Exit", color: "#008A00"}
];

function findCategory(category) {
  return myCategories.find(function(element) {
    return element.category === category;
  });
}

console.log(findCategory("start"));
// output: { category: "start", name: "Start", color: "#AC193D" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use *nullhack* for that purpose, it tries to access property of `null`, which is an error:

```
try {
  [1,2,3,4,5]
  .forEach(
    function ( val, idx, arr ) {
      if ( val == 3 ) null.NULLBREAK;
    }
  );
} catch (e) {
  // e <=> TypeError: null has no properties
}
//
```

Comment: Why not just `throw BREAK`?

Comment: You can simply use `FOOBARED` and it would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```
var wageType = types.filter(function(element){
  if(e.params.data.text == element.name){
    return element;
  }
});
console.dir(wageType);
```

Comment: Is this  right usage of filter method? I guess callback returns a boolean that regardless of it, callback is called array elements until the last one.

Comment: The question says "short circuit", filter does not.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***for of*** instead ***forEach***.

```
const timeSlots = [
  "0:00am", "0:30am", "1:00am", "1:30am", "2:00am", "2:30am", "3:00am", "3:30am",
  "4:00am", "4:30am", "5:00am", "5:30am", "6:00am", "6:30am", "7:00am", "7:30am",
  "8:00am", "8:30am", "9:00am", "9:30am", "10:00am", "10:30am", "11:00am", "11:30am",
  "12:00pm", "12:30pm", "1:00pm", "1:30pm", "2:00pm", "2:30pm", "3:00pm", "3:30pm",
  "4:00pm", "4:30pm", "5:00pm", "5:30pm", "6:00pm", "6:30pm", "7:00pm", "7:30pm",
  "8:00pm", "8:30pm", "9:00pm", "9:30pm", "10:00pm", "10:30pm", "11:00pm", "11:30pm"
];

for (let time of timeSlots) {
  if (time === "5:30am") {
    break; // Stop the iteration when you reach "5:30am"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array.prototype.every` function, which provide you the utility to break the looping. See example here [Javascript documentation on Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @bobince, upvoted.

Also, FYI:

Prototype.js has something for this purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $$('a').each(function(el, idx) {
    if ( /* break condition */ ) throw $break;
    // do something
  });
</script>
```

`$break` will be catched and handled by Prototype.js internally, breaking the "each" cycle but not generating external errors.

See [Prototype.JS API](http://prototypejs.org/doc/1.6.0/enumerable/each.html) for details.

jQuery also has a way, just return false in the handler to break the loop early:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('a').each( function(idx) {
    if ( /* break condition */ ) return false;
    // do something

  });
</script>
```

See [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `forEach` syntax, this is a way to keep it efficient (although not as good as a regular for loop). Check immediately for a variable that knows if you want to break out of the loop.

This example uses a anonymous function for creating a *function scope* around the `forEach` which you need to store the *done* information.

```js
(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById('printed-result');
    var done = false;
    [1,2,3,4].forEach(function(item){
        if(done){ return; }
        var text = document.createTextNode(item);
        element.appendChild(text);
        if (item === 2){
          done = true;
          return;
        }
    });
})();
```

```html
<div id="printed-result"></div>
```

My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to break based on the value of elements that are already in your array as in your case (i.e. if break condition does not depend on run-time variable that may change after array is assigned its element values) you could also use combination of [slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) and [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) as follows.

If you need to break when forEach reaches 'Apple' you can use

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var fruitsToLoop = fruits.slice(0, fruits.indexOf("Apple"));
// fruitsToLoop = Banana,Orange,Lemon

fruitsToLoop.forEach(function(el) {
    // no need to break
});
```

As stated [in W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) the slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object. The original array will not be changed.

See it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ula/6djbwh1c/)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try wrapping the function in a Promise?

The only reason I bring it up is that I am using a function in an API that acts in a similar manner to forEach. I don't want it to keep iterating once it finds a value, and I need to return something so I am simply going to resolve a Promise and do it that way.

```
traverseTree(doc): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node, index) => {
    //the above function is the one I want to short circuit.
      if(node.data.id === doc.id) {
        return resolve(node);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then all you need to do is do something with the result like

```
this.traverseTree(doc).then((result) => {
   this.doSomething(result);
});
```

My above example is in typescript, simply ignore the types. The logic should hopefully help you "break" out of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, a bit counter intuitively, **you don't actually have to!**

There are alternative solutions that will make your code look much neater as well, a win-win situation.

By filtering the array before applying your `forEach`, the break/return early won't be necessary.

```
function isOne(num) { 
    return num === 1; 
}

function processElement(num, index) { 
    console.log(num, index);
} 

[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5].filter(isOne)
                  .forEach(processElement);
```

If necessary, you can `map` your elements to add on some additional information:

```
function doPreCalculation(num) { 
    return num / 2;
}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5].map(doPreCalculation)
                  .filter(isOne)
                  .forEach(processElement);
```

You can use these methods on Iterators aswell. Collections like `NodeList` can be turned into an Iterator with `NodeList.values()`.

Comment: This isnt true for things like NodeList where forEach exists but filter and map do not

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the most efficient, since you still cycle all the elements, but I thought it might be worth considering the very simple:

```
let keepGoing = true;
things.forEach( (thing) => {
  if (noMore) keepGoing = false;
  if (keepGoing) {
     // do things with thing
  }
});
```

Comment: `continue` is a keyword, your code is a syntax error.

Comment: Given that you're using ES6 anyway, you should just switch to a `for of` loop and `break;` from that as usual.

Comment: fixed, and true -- but was mostly using es6 for brevity

Answer (score -2):

you can follow the code below which works for me:

```
 var     loopStop = false;
YOUR_ARRAY.forEach(function loop(){
    if(loopStop){ return; }
    if(condition){ loopStop = true; }
});
```

Comment: Why the -1? it isn't uglier than catching an exception, that is a bigger hack IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

I know it not right way. It is not break the loop.
It is a Jugad

```js
let result = true;
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(el) {
    if(result){
      console.log(el);
      if (el === 2){
        result = false;
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

#### Breaking out of built-in `Array.prototype.map` function esp in React

The key thing to note here is the use of statement `return` to BREAK

```
let isBroken = false;

colours.map(item => {
    if (isBroken) {
        return;
    }
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        isBroken = true;
        return;
    }
});
```

More information here: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/break+out+of+map+javascript

Answer (score -2):

In fact, I don't understand the reward for this old question. But if you really want to interrupt the foreach cycle, using only the foreach cycle, you can use the second parameter of the method to save the original array after its zeroing. Something like this:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
array.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);
    if(el === 1) {
        array = [...this];
        this.length = 0;
    }
}, array);
console.log(array);
```

P.S. I am in no way not advise that this should be done. On the contrary, I advise you to bypass my answer and use the previous best suggestions. Best regards.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a variant of `forEach` that allows for `break`, `continue`, `return`, and even `async`/`await`: (example written in TypeScript)

```
export type LoopControlOp = "break" | "continue" | ["return", any];
export type LoopFunc<T> = (value: T, index: number, array: T[])=>LoopControlOp;

Array.prototype.ForEach = function ForEach<T>(this: T[], func: LoopFunc<T>) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        const controlOp = func(this[i], i, this);
        if (controlOp == "break") break;
        if (controlOp == "continue") continue;
        if (controlOp instanceof Array) return controlOp[1];
    }
};

// this variant lets you use async/await in the loop-func, with the loop "awaiting" for each entry
Array.prototype.ForEachAsync = async function ForEachAsync<T>(this: T[], func: LoopFunc<T>) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        const controlOp = await func(this[i], i, this);
        if (controlOp == "break") break;
        if (controlOp == "continue") continue;
        if (controlOp instanceof Array) return controlOp[1];
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
function GetCoffee() {
    const cancelReason = peopleOnStreet.ForEach((person, index)=> {
        if (index == 0) return "continue";
        if (person.type == "friend") return "break";
        if (person.type == "boss") return ["return", "nevermind"];
    });
    if (cancelReason) console.log("Coffee canceled because: " + cancelReason);
}
```

Comment: This would require anyone to get back and read the Array prototype which seems not trivial and a waste of time

Comment: No, the "continue", "break", and "return" strings/operators are processed within the `ForEach` function (it's _not_ the generic `forEach` function) -- the caller does not need to read anything on the Array prototype. That said, I don't actually use the solution above in production code -- it's just showing how one could accomplish those various operators within a `forEach`-like function, if they wished to.

Comment: Yes. And still - if I would encounter this - it would not be clear at first look.

Answer (score -6):

```
const Book = {"Titles":[                          
    {"Book3" : "BULLETIN 3"},
    {"Book1" : "BULLETIN 1"},
    {"Book2" : "BULLETIN 2"}    
]}

const findbystr = function(str) { 
    Book.Titles.forEach(function(data) { 
        if (typeof data[str] != 'undefined') {
            return data[str];
        } 
    }, str) 
}

book = findbystr('Book1');

console.log(book);
```

Comment: I like this approach (I've edited the code so that the value is immediately returned from the function when found) - if you were to write up how the return within the forEach has the effect of a break statement you'd probably accrue some up votes for this option.

Answer (score -6):

I use `return false` and it works for me.