# Coffeescript: Break out of a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Array.forEach HowTo break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/javascript-array-foreach-howto-break)

Given that I have a forEach loop, how do I break out of that loop in case X is true?

For example:

```
user.forEach (x,i) ->

                    if x.status == "available"
                        -- I want to break here -
```

Thanks

Comment: THis is actually covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/javascript-array-foreach-howto-break

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, don't.  `forEach` is meant to be essentially "functional".  You could break it with an exception, but exceptions should be used for "exceptional" conditions, not control flow.

If you mean to break, you don't mean a functional form, you mean an iteration.  Use a `for` loop.

Comment: Or, alternatively, use something like jQuery's [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), which will break if you return `false`.

Comment: I agree with this, but I'm not sure the word "functional" is right, even in scare quotes; the whole point of `forEach` is to create side effects.

Comment: Isaac, compare forEach with, eg, map, with the loop body as a closure.

Comment: Sure, you *can* create side effects with `map` by modifying your enclosed variables, but that's using it non-functionally.

Comment: And you can do things in a forEach that don't have side-effects.