# How Can disable and enable RequiredFieldValidator for controls with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

in a page I have two radio-button which based which-one selected I will show some controls in this page by using classes called 'person' and 'organization'. Moreover, I want to check user enter correct data in input-text controls. How can I validta data in clientside?
 for example:

```
<input runat="server" id="txtnationalid" maxLength="10" name="txtnationalid" class='person ltr glow-onfocus customerCode required number' dir="ltr" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="txtcodecv1" ErrorMessage="it can not be null" ControlToValidate="txtnationalid" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" id="txtcodev2" ErrorMessage="it's not in correct format" ControlToValidate="txtnationalid" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<input runat="server" id="txteconomiccode" maxLength="15" name="txteconomiccode" class='organization ltr glow-onfocus customerCode required number' dir="ltr" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" id="txtcodecv3" ErrorMessage="economiccode required" ControlToValidate="txteconomiccode"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704039/enable-disable-aspvalidators-using-jquery#answer-9803857

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery for this

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>


 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" class="required"/>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[see here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) for mode details

Comment: how does it validate my controls? (for example text boxes)