# Break statement in javascript array map method

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Is there a way so that I can break out of array map method after my condition is met ? I tried the following which throws `"Illegal Break Statement" Error.` This is some random example I came up with.

```
var myArray = [22,34,5,67,99,0];

var hasValueLessThanTen = false;

myArray.map(function (value){
    if(value<10){
      hasValueLessThanTen = true;
      break;
    }
  }
);
```

We can do using `for` loops, but I wanted to know whether we can accomplish the same using `map` method ?

Comment: It is in essence a duplicate of the question that Rob W refers to. However, the source of this misunderstanding is the wrong usage of `map` method, which is intended to, hmmm, map values, so it's not supposed to stop the iteration

Comment: @Yoni is correct. If the OP is looking for a breakable forEach loop, consider uing methods such as [`[].every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (return `true` to continue, non-`true` to break) or [`[].some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - return true to break, non-true to continue.

Comment: alternatively [`[].reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).  Passing `[]` as a second argument, and only modifying when conditions are met.

Comment: Also I don't understand why this was marked as a duplicate.  The linked question is about `forEach` which has a much different solution.

Comment: @SandyGifford Agreed. Voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Since this question is still closed, here's an alternate solution:

https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/YBNPpX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384888/1929115

Answer (score 281, accepted):

That's not possible using the built-in [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). However, you could use a simple `for`-loop instead, if you do not intend to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) any values:

```
var hasValueLessThanTen = false;
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] < 10) {
    hasValueLessThanTen = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Or, as suggested by `@RobW`, use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if there exists at least one element that is less than 10. It will stop looping when some element that matches your function is found:

```
var hasValueLessThanTen = myArray.some(function (val) { 
  return val < 10;
});
```

Comment: I appreciated the .some example even though Rob had already mentioned it. People don't always look in the comments, but typically atleast scan the code samples!

Comment: Why isn't it possible with the `Array.prototype.map` ?

Comment: @Vadorequest I did post the question when I was js newbie, `Array.prototype.map` was not supposed to be used that way at all, it is a helper method for a whole different usecase where you want to transform every element of a given array into a different variant. So, when it's going to be about "every element", you would never need a "break" statement, if you need a break statement it means maybe you don't need a map.

I posted this question because I was trying to use that as a `iterator`, if you need iterator then go for the simple `for` loop or `forEach` in conjunction with `return`

Comment: Appears that `for` is faster than `some`:  https://jsperf.com/array-some-vs-loop

Comment: @MudassirAli I hope you can accept this answer no?