# How to return from a higher function

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
function foo() {
  someArray.map(bar) { 
    if (whatever)
      return; // I want to return from the foo function
    return bar.something // Here I return to map function
  }
}
```

Here is my current solution:

```
 let flag = false
 function foo() {
   someArray.map(bar) { 
     if (whatever){
       flag = true
     }
     return bar.something // Here I return to map function
   }
 }
 if (flag === true) {
   return;
 }
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I guess you want to break out of the `map` function. You can't do that.

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. You want `find`, not `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break your map function. But you don't use results of `map`. If you want to break your `map` after any condition you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) array method instead of it.

For example:

```
let flag = false;
function foo() {
   someArray.some(bar) { 
     if (!whatever){
         return false;
     }
     flag = true;
     return true;
   }
 }
 if (flag === true) {
   return;
 }
```

Or you can call any function inside `some` instead of using `flag` variable

```
function foo() {
   someArray.some(bar) { 
     if (!whatever){
         return false;
     }
     callYourCodeHere()
     return true;
   }
 }
```

Or something like this:

```
function foo() {
   const anySuccess = someArray.some(bar) { 
     return !!whatever;
   }
   if(anySuccess) {
       callYourCodeHere();
   }
 }
```