# Break out of map

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, if-statement

so i have this problem where if the value in the array is higher than entered value it should do something and then stop the loop and don't touch the remaining values in the array.. Here's the code so far:

```
const percentages = [];
let enteredValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);

range.map((rangeValue, i) => {
  if (rangeValue <= enteredValue) {
    percentages.push(100);
    enteredValue = enteredValue - rangeValue;
  } else {
    percentages.push(enteredValue * 100 / (rangeValue));

    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break statement in javascript array map method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method)

Answer (score 21):

Using `.some` you can get iteration functionally similar to `.forEach`, `map` or `for` loop but with the ability to `break` through `return` instead.

```js
range.some(function(rangeValue , i) {
  if (rangeValue <= enteredValue) {
    percentages.push(100);
    enteredValue = enteredValue - rangeValue;
    return true
  }
   percentages.push(enteredValue * 100 / (rangeValue));
});
```

Read more about `.some` in `es6` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 7):

Just use a good old for loop:

```
 const percentages = [];
 let enteredValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);

 for(const range of ranges) {
   percentages.push(Math.min(100, (enteredValue / range) * 100));
   enteredValue -= range;
   if(enteredValue <= 0) break;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are perfectly sufficient. However, I would like to add that the `map` function isn't best used for performing iterations. What the `map` function does is perform the as argument passed in callback on every element of the array. It then **returns the new array**. So map is more usefull when you are in need of a mutated copy of the Array (e.g. all the elements multiplied by 10).

For your purposes other logic like a regular for loop will be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` instead of `map`. The `reduce` senses a change in the original array.

```
let enteredValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);

const percentages = range
    .slice(0) // if you don't want to mess up the original array
    .reduce((percentages, rangeValue, _, rangeCopyArray) => {
        if (rangeValue <= enteredValue) {
            percentages.push(100);
            enteredValue -= rangeValue;
        } else {
            percentages.push(enteredValue * 100 / rangeValue);
            rangeCopyArray.length = 0; // the loop ends here
        }
        return percentages;
    }, [])
```

or shorter but less clear

```
const percentages = [...range].reduce(({p, eV}, rV, _, arr) => ({
    eV: eV-rV, 
    p: [...p, rV <= eV ? 100 : eV*100/rV + (arr.length = 0)]
}), {p: [], eV: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)}).p;
```