# stop performing map function on state if certain condition for one time is met

Tags: reactjs

```
this.state = { glasses :[{id:0,,value:100, show:true,},
                            {id:1,,value:150, show:false},
                            {id:2, value:200, show:true,},
                            {id:3, value:300, show:false,} .  ]
}
```

I have this data in states. I need to iterate this state through map and If i encounter show:true, it should stop iteration. like it breaks out of map function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break statement in javascript array map method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method)

Comment: if you want to break out of iteration you should use a for-loop or forEach for that, not map.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a *for-loop* instead?

I am suggesting it because seems it isn't possible to use *break* on *map*. A similar question was ask here: [Break statement in javascript array map method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. The right thing to do when somebody's question is answered in a different Q&A is vote to close as a duplicate - you'll be able to do this once you have some reputation, in the meantime it's best not to use the "answer" feature as a substitute.

Comment: I tried this link but not been able to change that particular show to false

Comment: Could you explain it better? @DibakarJayjot

Comment: tried using "for loop" and  if "show" is "true" then change it to "false" only once @TheMaysk

Comment: Are you using React? If so, maybe this issue is related to React and its state manipulation.

Comment: Are you using _this.setState_ to set the new state?

Comment: Yes, I am using this.setState

Comment: So, try to open another question tagged as react or add more information to the current one. This may help everyone to solve this issue.