# How to break a loop inside inline if in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-map

I would like to stop the loop inside `bedsAssign.map` if `row.id` is not equal to `u.tenant_id` but putting `break;` doesn't work.

```
{tenants.map((row) =>
                 bedsAssign.map(
                   (u) =>
                     row.id !== u.tenant_id && (
                       <MenuItem key={row.id} value={row.id}>
                         {row.fullName}
                       </MenuItem>
                        break; --> not working
                     )
                 )
               )}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break statement in javascript array map method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method)

Comment: Arrays methods are not interruptible. You can skip a single iteration with `return`. You can filter out what you don't want before the map though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `filter` before `map` to remove all `bedsAssign` items which are not matched with current `row.id`

```
{
  tenants.map((row) =>
    bedsAssign
      .filter((u) => row.id !== u.tenant_id)
      .map((u) => (
        <MenuItem key={row.id} value={row.id}>
          {row.fullName}
        </MenuItem>
      ))
  )
}
```

If you want to break the loop, you can try to use `some` or `find` with a proper `return` for `map`

```
{
  tenants.map((row) => {
    const isAssigned = bedsAssign.some((u) => row.id !== u.tenant_id)
        return isAssigned ? (<MenuItem key={row.id} value={row.id}>
          {row.fullName}
        </MenuItem>) : null    
  })
}
```

Comment: This almost work. After the loop filters the item, it gives me the result I need, but the loop began to loop again and the next item that it filtered doesn't give me correct result. So I need something to stop the loop once the condition is met. If it's possible

Comment: So you mean you only filter it once and the next loop should not filter anything? @JohnMichaelVicmudo

Comment: The loop should stop once the condition is met.

Comment: For a better understanding of what I'm trying to show. I'm making a boarding house system. Each tenant can only be assigned in 1 bed. And what I'm trying to show here is all the tenant that is available and wasn't assigned to any bed. To know if the tenant is assigned or not, I used u.tenant_id as a foreign key in the condition of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not break any array methods like forEach, filter, map etc. If you encounter a scenario where you want your loop to break then you should use traditional for loop.

Answer (score -1):

use a `filter` instead of `map` for bedsAssign:

```
{tenants.map((row) =>
                 bedsAssign.filter(
                   (u) =>
                     row.id !== u.tenant_id && (
                       <MenuItem key={row.id} value={row.id}>
                         {row.fullName}
                       </MenuItem>
                     )
                 )
               )}
```

the filter is going to only fill in the items that are meeting the condition you want.

EDIT: I noticed that you want to break once condition is met, this would work in this case:

```
{tenants.map((row) =>
                 for(let i of bedsAssign){
                     if(row.id !== i.tenant_id && (
                       <MenuItem key={row.id} value={row.id}>
                         {row.fullName}
                       </MenuItem>
                     )){
                         break
}
}
                 )
               )}
```

Comment: I'm having an error when using for loop. The function is inside the render ( {loop function} )