# Is resetting the array a valid way to break from Array.forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking for an easy way to break out of forEach. This answer mentions using the some method, but that doesn't give you the index of the current element: [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

I found that setting the array to false will break the forEach "loop". Is that valid or a hack?

Comment: Sorry, hit enter in the tags box.

Comment: "doesn't give you the index of the current element" - it does for me. It's the second argument.

Comment: Please show us some example code for "*setting the array to false*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by setting its `.length` to the current index in the iteration, then yes, it's "valid", but be aware that in doing so, you're clearing any Array members from that point forward.

```
var arr = ["foo","bar","baz"];

console.log(arr.length); // 3

arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
    if (i == 1)
        arr.length = i;
    else 
        console.log(v);
});

console.log(arr.length); // 1
```

If you set the `.length` to `false`, you're effectively setting it to `0`, and so you're clearing the entire Array.

Using `.some` or `.every` seems more sensible to me.

---

I should note that the iteration doesn't necessarily stop, but your callback won't be invoked because the native `.forEach()` does not invoke the callback for non-existent properties. According to the spec, the length in cached.

This can be tested by expanding the Array during the iteration. The added members are never reached.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the index of the current element is passed as the 2nd parameter to the callback function:

Syntax:  ***array.some(callback[, thisObject])***

```
callback is invoked with three arguments: 
   1. the value of the element
   2. the index of the element
   3. the Array object being traversed
```

See [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

---

More importantly...

Is there any reason you can't do it the normal way:

```
var matchIndex = -1;
for (i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    if (isFound(someArray[i])) {
        matchIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
alert("Mathing index: " + matchIndex);
```

Comment: My bad. I just found out about this method. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up doing it the normal way. I just like the way .each() works in jQuery.