# Order of resolutions in loop attached to window.resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var res = [1024, 1280, 1600],
    vals = [1, 2, 3];
```

I want to assign a value to a variable on `window.resize` depending on the resolution that matches in the `res` array. So i came up with this:

```
function update() {
  res.forEach(function( res, i ) {
    someVariable = $(window).width() < res ? vals[ i ] : 4;
  });
}

$(window).resize( update );
```

The problem is that it only works for 1600 but not for all the other resolutions. But if I do the following (hard-coded) it works just fine:

```
function update() {
  someVariable = $(window).width() < 1024 ? 1
   : $(window).width() < 1280 ? 2
   : $(window).width() < 1600 ? 3
   : 4;
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work dynamically?

**Edit:** I'm thinking I have to break the loop at some point but can't figure out the condition to test...

Comment: Where do you define `winWidth` variable?

Comment: @undefined: I see what you mean, I'm using `$(window).width()` actually so that's not the problem. I'll update that.

Comment: @elclanrs Adil's answer doesn't work. Please accept the other answer so that if people with a similar question find this question, they can find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` the loop when first time the condition becomes true and value is assigned to `someVariable` as with width less then 1024 is also less then 1280 and 1600 and finally you will get the last one which is 1600.

```
function update() {
  res.forEach(function( res, i ) {
    if(winWidth < res)
     {
       someVariable = vals[ i ];
       return; //break the loop here
     }        
  });
}
```

**Edit** as per AlexStack comments, to break the forEach loop as dicussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break) you can use the following technique.

```
function update() {
  var exp = {}; 
  try
  {
    res.forEach(function( res, i ) {
       if(winWidth < res)
       {
          someVariable = vals[ i ];
          throw exp;
       }        
    });
  }catch(ex){
      if (e!==exp) throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks this is what I was looking for. I had to actually `return false` for it to work. Then I set the default value on the `else` statement. Long day ~

Comment: the `return` statement DOES NOT intettupr the `forEach()` loop! It merely interrupts the current function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: I'm using jQuery's `$.each` with `return false`. My question was merely about "where to break". This helped.

Comment: @Adil please read the link I provided. The `break` command really doesn't interrupt a function. You need to throw an exception. `for` loop is a better candidate than `forEach` for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `forEach` is not terminated once a satisfactory result is found. You can solve it like this:

```
function update() {
  res.sort();//to make sure any future additions to the array doesn't break the order
  for( var i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ) {
    if ( winWidth < res[i] ) {
      someVariable = i + 1;//javascript arrays are 0-based. Add 1 to make it 1-based
      return;//terminate the loop when the result is found
    }
  }
  //if no result is found, this will be executed after the for loop
  someVariable = res.length;
  return;
}
```

PS. this solution doesn't need the `vals` array.