# EmberJS: is it possible to break from forEach?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to break from the forEach iterator in Ember?

I tried to return false in the callback (a la jQuery) but it does not work.

Thanks!
PJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ember uses the native `Array.prototype.forEach` if it's available, and emulates it if not. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-metal/lib/array.js#L45.

JavaScript's `forEach` doesn't support breaking. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thanks James and all. I guess I will toArray() and use the jQuery iterator instead for the time being.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
[1,2,3].some(function(element) {
    return true; // Break the loop
});

[1,2,3].every(function(element) {
    return false; // Break the loop
});
```

More informations [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I dont think so cfr James, looking at the [foreach](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/enumerable.js#L192) code, you can see that it uses a for loop under the hood. You can throw an exception, but thats like writing spagetti code.
But it might be possible, you can do a feature request at github? Or write your own implementation that breaks in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#find](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_find) and return true to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using `toArray` can potentially remove the order of the array, which sort of defeats the purpose.  You could use a normal for loop but use `objectAt` to make it work for you.

```
var emberArray = [ ... Array of Ember objects ... ],
    min = 3,
    max = emberArray.get('length'),
    targetObject;

for( var i = min; i < max; i++ ){
    targetObject = emberArray.objectAt( i );

    if( targetObject.get('breakHere') ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This has the added benefit of allowing you to start at a certain index, so you can loop through the smallest number of items.