# Unable to break from array foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
   var statusArray = new Array();

   statusArray.forEach(function (item) {                
                 if (checkStatus != item) {
                     disableall = true;
                     return false;
                }
             });
```

I am returning false but not able break from foreach loop.

Comment: Possible solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do break a [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop

> Note : There is no way to stop or break a forEach loop. The solution
>   is to use Array.every or Array.some. See example below.

Since you have tagged it using jQuery, use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) if possible

```
var statusArray = new Array();

$.each(statusArray, function (i, item) {
    if (checkStatus != item) {
        disableall = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Else try Array.every()/Array.some() as given in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Breaking_a_loop)