# javascript function ignores return statement

Tags: javascript

I have a function returning null by default, and another value by condition.

```
var getName = function(boxid){
    var boxes = localStorage.getItem("boxes");
    if((boxes != "" )&& (typeof boxes != "undefined") &&( boxes != null))
    {
        boxes = JSON.parse(boxes);
        boxes.forEach(function(box){
            if(box.id == boxid)
            {
                console.log("box.name: "+ box.name+ " boxid: "+ box.id+ " : "+ boxid);
                return box.name;
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
};
```

the correct array-entry gets found. but the return statemant doesn't return it,
it's ignored.

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Can you show the code that uses the returned value?

Comment: I just call it alert(getName(boxid));
Isn't the return statement of the if-condition ending the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break) - especially the SECOND answer: _shiny-new-toy disease_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your return statement isn't working is because it is local to the `forEach`'s callback, and not related to your `getName`-function.

You should use a normal `for`-loop instead:

```
var getName = function(boxid){
    var boxes = localStorage.getItem("boxes");
    if((boxes != "" )&& (typeof boxes != "undefined") &&( boxes != null))
    {
        boxes = JSON.parse(boxes);
        for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            if(boxes[i].id == boxid)
            {
                console.log("boxName: "+ boxes[i].name+ " boxID: "+ boxes[i].id+ " : "+ boxid);
                return boxes[i].name;
            }
        };
    }
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because they are in different scope.

You could use `filter` and `map` function:

```
boxes = JSON.parse(boxes);

// the result will be an array of box name
return boxes.filter(function(box){
    return box.id = boxid;
}).map(function(box) {
    return box.name;
});

// if the box id is unqic, then just get the first one.
```

Comment: it returns the entire boxex-content.

Answer (score 1):

The `return box.name;` is for the function inside `forEach`.

The function `getName` only have `return null;`