# stop an if statement javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, foreach

I have an if statement but need it to "break" if the first condition is met but AFTER I have completed some processes.  The if statement is wrapped inside a forEach statement in Angular.

```
angular.forEach($scope.obj, function ( value, key) {
  if( id == key) {
    delete $scope.obj[id];
    result.clicked = false;
    //break here, don't run the else
  } else {
    $scope.obj[id] = result;
    result.clicked = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: just `return` or `break`

Comment: where would I put them? can you be more specific? I tried return where the comment is but that did nothing because the loop kept running

Comment: There is no simple way to break from an `angular.foreach` and the reason why is explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263). You can try something like what is explained in the top answer of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this, Angular forEach loop can't break on condition match.
Use native **FOR** loop instead of `angular.forEach`, Because `for` will allow you to `break` in between.

Comment: Thanks!  I used a regular `for (var key in $scope.obj){}` and was able to break on the if statement.

Comment: That's it! Solved... :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular documentation says nothing about stopping forEach, it seems it cannot be stopped.
Maybe you should use something like [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
On the other hand, maybe you can stop it throwing an error... but it seems a dirty way to do it.

Comment: [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would work as well.

Comment: Yes, more or less one is the opposite of the other: one works while true is returned, the other while false

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular.forEach is async, you can not break, because there is no loop. If you use a normal loop, you can break as usual.

Comment: angular.forEach is not async

Comment: Woops, it is not indeed. But there is no break'ing in anulars implementation.