# How to break a loop with the EJS template language?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ejs

I am developping a simple web application with sails.js.

In my frontend code, i'm looping over an array of objects sent by the controller, and i am searching for a specific object. I'd like to break the loop once the object has been found. Is there a clean way to do that using the ejs template language ?

I coulnd't find anything about it on the EJS official website, nor on sails website.

**I naively tried this until now :**

```
<% objects.forEach(function(object)  { %>
    <% if(object.someId == someValue) {%>
        <%= object.name %>
        <% break %> <!-- This raise an illegal statement exception -->
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

**The following code works as expected, but i'm looking for a cleaner solution if any**

```
<% var found = false %>
<% objects.forEach(function(object)  { %>
    <% if(object.someId == someValue && !found) {%>
        <%= object.name %>
        <% found = true %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an EJS-related question.

`break` statement terminates the current loop. While you are not inside a loop. You are inside callback function, that's called by `forEach` method once per array element. There's no ability to interrupt forEach (see [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)). But, if you need it, you may use `for` loop for a clean solution:

```
<% for (var l = objects.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) { %>
    <% object = objects[i]%>
    <% if(object.someId == someValue) {%>
        <%= object.name %>
        <% break %> <!-- This will work as expected -->
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```