# Appending string to value of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi Im populating select > options using my json using below code. Here my doubt is I want to add custom attribute only if value is "IN". Anyone can help to achieve this

```
$.each( data, function( i, val ) {
    items.push( "<option value='" + val.countryCode + "'>" + val.countryName + "</option>" );
});
```

Comment: What did you try? Simply check your `IN` value in the function (if/ else)

Comment: Add if condition, if(val.countrycode == 'IN'){...}

Comment: I dont want to check "val.countrycode" in loop. Is it possible to add attr once array populated

Comment: "I dont want" --- any technical argumentation behind this behaviour?

Comment: I thought there will be best alternate to do this instead of checking in loop(FYI array length is 250), after array populated

Comment: "best" --- the best from what perspective? `if` statement takes one line. Is a single line too complicated?

Comment: Here I dont meant number of line. My doubt is, is it necessary to do if condition?

Comment: Well, any problems with `if`?

Comment: @zerkms Whats your problem, I don't think your trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each( data, function( i, val ) {
   if(val.countryCode !='IN') {
     items.push( "<option value='" + val.countryCode + "'>" + val.countryName + "</option>" );
  }
   else {
     items.push( "<option data-id=1 value='" + val.countryCode + "'>" + val.countryName + "</option>" );
  }
});
```

Comment: It makes sense to teach newbies with something that doesn't look like spaghetti: 1. with `{}` that enclose `if-else` bodies 2. with proper indentation 3. without insane amount of duplication

Comment: the above answer is absolutely correct with proper formatting and inside ifelse statement we can give one line without {} so its not the issue...

Comment: It is syntactically correct. But it's not smart to teach newbies with terrible code.

Comment: Still terrible, sorry. Indentation, braces position, duplication. This piece of code won't pass a code review in a decent company.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$.each( data, function( i, val ) {
    items.push( "<option value='" + val.countryCode +( val.countryCode == "IN" ? "data-attr = 'value'" : "" ;) "'>" + val.countryName + "</option>" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's only possible with a `if` condition. You can increase speed by breaking on the first found result, but you need to use a for-loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<countryArr.length;i++) {
  if(countryArr[i].countryCode === "IN") {
    items.push( "<option value='" + countryArr[i].countryCode + "'>" + countryArr[i].countryName + "</option>" );
    break;
  }
});
```

If you want to use `forEach` see [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break). But a some expression might be easier:

```
countryArr.some(function(data) {
    var check=countryArr[i].countryCode ==="IN";
    if(check) {
       items.push("<option value='" + data.countryCode + "'>" + data.countryName + "</option>");
    }
    return check; //some stops, if it returns true
});
```

ECMA6 will introduce a `find` method so you can shortcut this:

```
items.push(countryArr.find(function(data) {
  return data.countryCode === "IN";
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$.each( data, function( i, val ) {
  items.push( "<option "+ (val.countryCode === "IN" && "data-id=1" || "") + " value='" +  val.countryCode + "'>" + val.countryName + "</option>" );
});`
```

Comment: Even though technically it will work - it's terribly unreadable.

Comment: Just as every HTML generated by JS. That's why people (including me) created templating engines I created https://github.com/adriank/ACFrontend. But the question is about generating HTML in JS and this is one-liner:). Could be also val.countryCode === "IN" ? "data-id=1" : ""

Comment: "Just as every HTML generated by JS" --- not even close. You could introduce a local variable to hold the conditional expression evaluation result. Do you realize that `+` has a higher precendence than a conditional operator? `+` also has the higher precedence than `===`. So it will run `"<option "+ val.countryCode` first. That's why I mentioned it's unreadable and now I say - it's not maintainable and just wrong.

Comment: @zerkms it's just a matter of taste. For me thinking about variable names, "var" and managing variables is extremely troublesome. It's better to read code from left to right like a book. In book you have 2 to 5 paragraphs per page and each paragraph has multiple lines. I like to see the same in source code. But of course JS doesn't look as elegant here as for example Python, for sure.

Comment: It has nothing to do with *taste*. So your book analogy fails as soon as you write an expression that you cannot (and you actually cannot, because your code is incorrect) evaluate in your head easily. `+` has higher precedence than a conditional operator. `'1' + true === true ? '2' : '3'` Check your *intuition* (must be *knowledge* actually)

Comment: Oh, and even after 2 days you haven't fixed the mistake. That's weird :-S

Comment: From what I see here you also can type and definitely have much more time than me, so why haven't you fix that?