# Self-terminate an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, terminate

How can I achieve the following?

Inside map function loop.
Terminate an if statement after it has been 'true' once.

```
array.prototype.map(function (data){
   if (true) {
      // Do something
      // Self destroy so I won't be available for next iteration
   }
});
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: I think this can be accomplished with a simple variable and a condition