# Breaking with return false from forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to break from the Object.keys().forEach loop with 'return false', but it doesn't seem to actually break from the loop. Am I doing anything wrong - is it possible to break from a forEach? Or should I use a different looping construct?

```
function findCollection(name){
            var ret = null;
            Object.keys(collections).forEach(function (key) {
                if (collections.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var coll = collections[key];
                    if(coll.uniqueName == name){
                        ret = coll;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: I also may not need hasOwnProperty for Object.keys, I just can't keep track of that stuff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374/3965755