# Returning true or false inside functions, I am a bit confused

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, scope, return

I have this function, for example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.query.token;
    if(!token) {
        res.render('auth'); // Authentication
    } else {
        authorizedUsers.forEach(function(user) {
            if(user.id == token) {
                console.log('found, nickname: ' + user.nickname);
                return true;
            }
        });
        console.log('not found');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Basically it's looping through the `authorizedUsers` array, and looking for an entry where `entry.id` equals the `token` variable.

What I wanted to do is, if found, to return true and stop the execution of the rest of the `app.get('/')...` block.

If not found, obviously the forEach loop has already gone through all entries, and eventually the execution arrives to the printing of "not found" and `return false;`.

For my current code, even though an entry is found, execution continues and I still get the 'not found' log.
[image]

Am I missing anything?

To simplify things, what I wanna do is:

1. Looping through all authorizedUsers entries, comparing entry.id to the token variable.
2. If found, print "found" to the console and stop the execution.
3. If not found, print "not found" to the console and stop the
   execution.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Following Michael's solution, this is my working code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.query.token;
    if(!token) {
        res.render('auth'); // Authentication
    } else {
        if(!authorizedUsers.some(function(user) {
            if(user.id == token)
                return true;
        })) {
            console.log('No entries found.');
        } else {
            console.log('Entries found!');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this:

```
authorizedUsers.some(function(user) {
    return user.id == token;
}
```

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: Thanks, I will set this as answer. I have also edited my own question with the solution using .some(). Thanks a lot @Michael! That was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach` function cannot be interrupted unless the code inside throws an exception.

So you could either do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Or just let it run through all the records doing something like this:

```
   var found = false;
   authorizedUsers.forEach(function(user) {
        if(user.id == token) found = true;
    });
    console.log('found? ', found);
```

Comment: Viola! I thought something was wrong with me, because I used to work with PHP Laravel for a long time and it worked like a charm the way I did it. I knew something is wrong. I am pretty new to Node. Thanks for your advise!