# How to return from the above nested function?

Tags: javascript

The below function will always return true, because the `return false;` returns the function passed to `forEach`.

```
function exampleFunction(array){
    array.forEach(function(element){
        if(element.condition){
            return false; 
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Now, obviously the below works:

```
function exampleFunction(array){
    var result = true;
    array.forEach(function(element){
        if(element.condition){
            result = false; 
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

but it's not ideal because it does unnecessary iterations. I know I could solve the problem by using a different loop to `forEach`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it keeping `forEach`. So, how can I return from the 'above' function in JavaScript when inside a nested function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can short circuit the `forEach` [by throwing an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374/1913729), but a better way would be to use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
function doesNotContainOnes(array){
    return !array.some(function(el) { return el === 1; });
}

document.body.innerHTML = doesNotContainOnes([5,9,6]) + '<br>'       // true
                        + doesNotContainOnes([5,9,6,'hi']) + '<br>'  // true
                        + doesNotContainOnes([5,9,6,1]) + '<br>';    // false
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to break a `.forEach` loop during the loop other than throwing an exception (but don't do that). Use a `for` loop if you need to break mid-way. If you really need a method or a function:

```
function forEach(arr, func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (func(arr[i], i) === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Or...
Array.prototype.softLoop = function(func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    ...
}

var my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
my_array.softLoop(function(element, index) {
    console.log(index, element);
    if (element == 2) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You could even modify it so you didn't need a flag outside the loop:

```
Array.prototype.softLoopReturnable = function(func) {
    for (var ret, i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        ret = func(arr[i], i);
        if (ret === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function exampleFunction(array){
  return !array.some(function(element){
    return element.condition;
  });
}
```

In the code above, `exampleFunction` will return `false` when it comes across the first `element` where `condition` is truthy or `true` if none are found.