# Javascript: how to match array and json?

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

How can I find there is a match between an array and a json?

```
var fields = [ { public_name: 'hello', code_name: 'world' },
  { public_name: 'particles', code_name: 'pm2.5' },
  { public_name: 'humidity', code_name: 'hum' } ]

var species = [{"code_name":"hum","public_name":"humidity"},
  {"code_name":"pm2.5","public_name":"particles"},
  {"code_name":"world","public_name":"hello"}]


fields.forEach(function(field, index) {       
    if (field.code_name === species.code_name) {
        console.log('match:' + code_name)
    }
});
```

The result should be:

```
match: world
match: pm2.5
match: hum
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `if (field.code_name === species[index].code_name) {
        console.log('match:' + field.code_name)
    }` you need to iterate and compare with each value in `species`, use `Array#some`

Comment: You need two loops to match exactly.

Comment: Do you need to compare all properties for match or even if 1 property is matching, message should be shown

Comment: You might like to look into something like [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim). It will give you access to lots of the new JavaScript features such as those used in the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hash table for lookup.

```js
var fields = [{ public_name: 'hello', code_name: 'world' }, { public_name: 'particles', code_name: 'pm2.5' }, { public_name: 'humidity', code_name: 'hum' }],
    species = [{ "code_name": "hum", "public_name": "humidity" }, { "code_name": "pm2.5", "public_name": "particles" }, { "code_name": "world", "public_name": "hello" }],
    match,
    hash = Object.create(null),
    getHashKey = function (o) { return o.public_name + '|' + o.code_name; };

fields.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[getHashKey(a)] = true;
});

match = fields.filter(function (a) {
    return hash[getHashKey(a)];
});

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) at this context,

```
fields.forEach(function(field, index) {       
   if(species.find((itm) => itm.code_name == field.code_name)) {
      console.log("match" , " : " , field.code_name)
   }
});
```

Or the better option would be using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) since it will return the result in Boolean's,

```
fields.forEach(function(field, index) {       
   if(species.some((itm) => itm.code_name == field.code_name)) {
      console.log("match" , " : " , field.code_name)
   }
});
```

Comment: Though I was going to do the same, do specify that `Array.find` has compatibility issues

Comment: @PranavCBalan Yeah, That would yield true/false unlike a find. find would return the matched element if any.

Comment: @Rajesh But eventually, browsers will start support ES6 shortly. So we have to start writing code in that. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but what about browsers like IE8 or IE9? At least you should mention it and if OP wants to use it for older browsers, he/she can add polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use newer JS features, you can just nest two loops like so.

```js
var fields = [
  { public_name: 'hello', code_name: 'world' },
  { public_name: 'hello', code_name: 'NO MATCH' },
  { public_name: 'particles', code_name: 'pm2.5' },
  { public_name: 'humidity', code_name: 'hum' }
];

var species = [
  {"code_name":"hum","public_name":"humidity"},
  {"code_name":"pm2.5","public_name":"particles"},
  {"code_name":"world","public_name":"hello"}
];

var matches = [];

fields.forEach(function(field, index) {
  species.forEach(function(spec) {
    if (spec.code_name === field.code_name) {
      matches.push(field.code_name);
    }
  });
});

document.getElementById('result').textContent = matches.join(', ');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You should short-circuit loop on match. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: Agreed, in theory. @teelou, if either array could grow bigger than a few thousand entries, you should consider performance and not continue looping after you have found a match.

Comment: for big arrays pre-hashing is much better