# How to break out from foreach loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am newbie in Javascrript. I have a variable having following details:

```
var result = false;
[{"a": "1","b": null},{"a": "2","b": 5}].forEach(function(call){
    console.log(call);
    var a = call['a'];
    var b = call['b'];
    if(a == null || b == null){
        result = false
        break;
    }
});
```

I want to break the loop if there is NULL value for a key. How can I do it?

Comment: What loop? `for (var i = 0...` etc, a literal `.forEach` or what?

Comment: What loop? I see json but no javascript.

Comment: Just say `break;` inside of the forloop inside of the if statement that checks for the NULL value.

Comment: After update: yes, it's a duplicate of what Robbie reported.

Comment: I did checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break link. However, I was not able to figure out the solution. Given link has simple(int,string) array.  In my array I have object and need to check whether any property has null value.

Comment: `var result = arr.every(obj => obj.a ===null || obj.b === null)` that's it. The second answer already mentions `.every` and all you need then is the check.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead of `.forEach()`

```
var myObj = [{"a": "1","b": null},{"a": "2","b": 5}]
var result = false

for(var call of myObj) {
    console.log(call)
    
    var a = call['a'], b = call['b']
     
    if(a == null || b == null) {
        result = false
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: What if one can only use `foreach`?

Comment: Why can you only use `.forEach`?

Comment: `for in` doesn't work for a `Map`. `for of` is not available in ES5. `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` needs to get values first, i.e. `map.values()`, I'm not sure if it harms performance because our WebGL app needs to loop through the map values every frame.

Comment: If you care about performance use `.forEach` and ignore next calls when you have your result, this is the most efficient way to do it in ES5. Note that ES5 doesn't have `Map` so your are probably using a polyfill like `core-js`, native objects (`{}`) are faster in this case and can be iterated using `for(var key in object)`.

Comment: you can also change the length of the array itself, this will cause the forEach to break

Comment: Best idea would be to use `.every` instead of `.forEach` as it behaves exactly the same, except that it escapes the loop when a falsy value is returned. [Source](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/foreach-break)