# loop through an object, jump out of it when the item is matched -Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I want to loop through a dynamic object, 
match the value,
if item matched, jump out of the loop...

Let say have an object:`{a:false:b:true,c:false}`
I want to do something like (with [loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#forOwn)),

```
_.fowOwn({a:1,b:2}, function (value, key) {
  console.log(key);
  if(value); break;
});
```

So this should log `(a & b)`.
How can I  `break` when the item is matched ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `_.find()`?

Comment: `So this should log (a & b)` - no, it shouldn't. Objects have no ordering, so iteration order is unspecified. Most browsers tend to keep it consistent but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: [short circuit loob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break). :)

Comment: @viaz the order doesn't matter in the real scenario, the purpose is to break when the condition is met.

Comment: @TooNDinDarkDevil Thanks, let me try

Comment: @Fahad Well, I wanted to make sure you weren't going in with the wrong assumption as _relying_ on iteration order of objects is both wrong and dangerous. Also wide-spread. At any rate,  why not use `find`? It is exactly what you want, isn't it?

Comment: @vlaz yes, `_.find` looks good, giving a hand on it

Comment: Thanks @vlaz, done it with `_.find`

Answer (score 0):

$.grep in jquery is the solution.
Example :

```js
var data = {
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "category": "cat1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "category": "cat2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "cat1"
    }]
};

var returnedData = $.grep(data.items, function (element, index) {
    return element.id == 1;
});


alert(returnedData[0].id + "  " + returnedData[0].category);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was looking for the solution with loadash or pure javascript.

Comment: `$.grep` is doubly unneeded with that example, as you can simply do `data.items.find(function(item) { return item.id===1} )`, there is no need for jQuery.