# Where does the return value go for a forEach callback?

Tags: javascript

... more specefically, is it possible to break out of a forEach loop.  In the code below the return statement in the if statement appears to do nothing.

This is because it is retuning to the callback function.

Here is a reference:

[msdn - forEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx)

```
// underscore equivalent "cornerstone" fails b.c. of storage duality
var newForEach = function (obj, func, con) {
    if (Pub.isType("Function", func)) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            if (func.call(con, obj[key], key, obj)) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Note, I'm not interested in using another method.  I'm curious as to **where** the return value goes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374

Answer (score 1):

The return value goes nowhere.

If you want to break out a `forEach`, then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead. It breaks when you return a truthy value.

Taken from the [MDN documentation on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the `forEach()` method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead. If available, the new methods [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) can be used for early termination upon true predicates as well.

Comment: Of course, if you're actually doing something for each element in an array and want to break out early, you *are* allowed to just use a `for` loop with `break`. That's still part of the language...

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of the loop, but the return value is unused.

Since `forEach` doesn't return anything itself, it wouldn't make much sense to collect return values from the callback.

To break out, you need to `throw` during the callback:

```
var newForEach = function (obj, func, con) {
    if (Pub.isType("Function", func)) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            if (func.call(con, obj[key], key, obj)) {
                throw new Error('something terrible happened!');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**However**, that looks like exceptions as flow control, which is a Very Bad Thing. If that is what you're doing, there are probably other array methods that will be more helpful: perhaps [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: What does `Array.prototype.forEach` actually return ... looks like undefined according to the docs ...