# jQuery $.each vs. JavaScript .forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Take the following two ways of removing an array of elements from the DOM using jQuery:

```
var collection = [...]; //  An array of jQuery DOM objects

// Using jQuery iteration
$(collection).each(function(index, element) { element.remove(); });

// Or as pointed out by Barmar
$(collection).remove();

// Using native iteration
collection.forEach(function(element) { element.remove(); });
```

Is there any real difference operationally? I'd expect, unless the browser interpreter/compiler is clever enough, that there would be additional unnecessary overhead with the former method, albeit probably minor if the array is small.

Comment: Your second is biased because it still uses jQuery. `collection.forEach(function(element) {element.parentNode.removeChild(element);})` is a fairer comparison.

Comment: No, `$(selector).each()` calls the function with the element as the argument, not the jQuery object.

Comment: Where does collection come from? Typically with jQuery you don't need to create your own  arrays of elements since jQuery objects do that for you

Comment: To iterate over an array, not the elements in a jQuery object, you use `$.each(array, function...)`, not `$(array).each(function...)`

Comment: @charlietfl Say for instance I'm appending elements to the DOM and wish to push them, as they're appended, to an array for quicker access instead of scanning the DOM again.

Comment: OK...then it's a matter of what are you pushing...jQuery objects or dom elements. If they are jQuery objects don't need to wrap them again in `$()`

Comment: @charlietfl jQuery objects since I'm using jQuery to select the DOM elements. Good point about re-wrapping. Edited again to make this clearer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Operationally* is a bit vague but here is how `$.each` is implemented.

[`each` implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L240)

`[].forEach()` would most likely be implemented in native code for each browser.

Without doing performance testing, they are pretty similar. Although if you can remove jQuery altogether that is at least a few kb the browser does not need to load.

Answer (score 6):

The comments on the original question are good for your specific scenario of wanting to remove individual items.

On a more general note, some other differences:

1) Array.forEach() obviously requires that you're iterating across an array.  The jQuery approach will let you iterate across the *properties* of an *object*.

2) jQuery.each() allows short-circuiting.  Check out this post that mentions use of "some()" and "every()" for doing similar things with pure js:

[How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 4):

Performance wise they both are similar [Perf test](https://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-js-foreach/10)

**forEach** is implemented native in the Browser which makes it easier to maintain for non-jquery developers while on the other hand **each** offers better readability.

Answer (score -2):

[Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a method that iterates over native Javascript arrays.

jQuery [collection.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is an iteration method implemented by hand by the jQuery team. a jQuery collection is not an array.

This was also more relevant when jQuery first came out, and Array.forEach was not implemented in any browsers.

Comment: Did you just answer based on the title…?

Comment: How does this answer the question?