# How to return from forEach leaving the embracing method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach

I want to iterate using `forEach` and, when the correct element's been located, return the value. I was under impression that a simple `return` inside the `forEach` would suffice but learned that the result in the calling statement was `undefined`.

So I had to declare an output variable scoped to the whole of the method and tick through all the elements, despite the fact that the right one's already been found. (The elements are unique.)

```
getMenuIndex(url) {
  let output = -1;

  this.menus.forEach(app => {
    app.subs.forEach(sub => {
      console.log(sub.link + " vs " + url);
      if (sub.link === url)
        // return sub.id;
        output = sub.id;
    });
  });

  return output;
}
```

This is code smell long way. Is there a neater way to pick the ID of the element matching the URL condition?

Comment: [There is no built-in break for forEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: Instead of `forEach` you can use `find`. With `Array.find` you can stop the iteration by returning `true`.

Comment: @Titus True but not applicable in my case. The thing, as shown in the example is a nested creature. In the actual program, the nesting has even more levels of depth. Otherwise, good suggestion, mate.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think that `typescript` tag is important here because it provides the context for the supposed use - as it was shown in the answer. Generally for..of is slower than forEach, but in transpiled TS ES5 target it is faster.

Comment: @estus, i dont see any typescript in the question, but anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, we have `for..of` in TypeScript and ES6 for such scenarios:

```
getMenuIndex(url) {
  for (const app of this.menus) {
    for (const sub of app.subs) {
      console.log(sub.link + " vs " + url);
      if (sub.link === url)
        return sub.id;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

It is very helpful in the cases where `forEach` limitations are evident, such as `await`/`yield` or `return`/`break`.

As the other answers say, there are array methods that may fit the case better. Although for TypeScript ES5 target `for..of` is transpiled to regular `for` and thus is the fastest solution per se.

Comment: I prefer the lambda styled expressions because they look to me more sexy. However, I see your point and you're probably right, so I agree with it.

Comment: Me probably too. With functional approach it would likely be something like `const { id = -1 } = this.menus.reduce(...).find(...) || {}; return id`, but it wouldn't be as effective, and it's a bit harder to read even if a developer is into FP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit with `true`.

```
function getMenuIndex(url) {
    let output = -1;
    this.menus.some(app => app.subs.some(sub => {
        if (sub.link === url) {
            output = sub.id;
            return true;
        }
    }));
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Yet, you are using `some` in a way **not** semantically compatible with the description you yourself quote. There are some people, with whom I sympathize, that consider this the equivalent of torturing cute little kittens.

Comment: @torazaburo, do you mean the wrong quote, or the use of some for not using the result of checking?