# Javascript function not returning false

Tags: javascript

This function is only returning true. I have added a console.log in the if block and it is called but the function doesn't return false.

```
function isUniform(List)
{
    var ele = List[0];
    List.forEach(function(item)
    {
        console.log(ele);
        if(ele !== item)
        {
            return false;
        }
    })
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what does this list have?

Comment: What are is the value of `ele`/`item`?

Comment: Just some numbers like [1,2,2,2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: Post a minimal verifiable example. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ele is always equal to first element of the list and then it is compared with every element of list through a foreach loop @thebluefox

Comment: @Vamsi yes for the first element it will be equal but then for the rest of the elements it is not equal.

Comment: Quick Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behaviour, the .forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead. Taken from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @JJJ so you are saying return false will not return the function and foreach will still run despite the return statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need another method for testing unifomity. Better use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which checks every value with the first item of the array and return `true`, if all elements are equal and `false` if not. The iteration stops with the first unequal element.

```
function isUniform(list) {
    return list.every(function(item, _, array) {
        return item === array[0];
    });
}
```

The used [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns always `undefined`:

> **`forEach()`** executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it always returns the value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) and is not chainable.

Comment: Cool! Learned a new thing. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code;

```
function isUniform(List)
{
    var res = true;
    var ele = List[0];
    List.forEach(function(item)
    {
        console.log(ele);
        if(ele !== item)
        {
            res = false;
            return;
        }
    })
    return res;
}
```

Comment: the `return;` is as redundant as in the original question :p