# How to filter out data which is present between two array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two a

```js
var statusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: false},
  {label: '3', checked: false},
  {label: '4', checked: false},
  {label: '5', checked: false},
];

var activeStatusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: true},
  {label: '2', checked: true},
];
```

I need to filter out activeStatusFilter such that any element in activeStatusFilter not present in statusFilter should be removed.
So the result of the function should be [{label: '1', checked: true}] because label: '2' is not present in status filter.

I have written a function to do the same but it always return an empty array.

```
const z = activeStatusFilter.filter( activeStatus =>
{
  let found = false;
  statusFilter.forEach(status => {
    console.log( activeStatus );
    console.log( "status", status )
    found =  ( activeStatus.label === status.label )
    return found
  })
  return found;
} )
```

I feel that in the forEach when `found =  ( activeStatus.label === status.label )` it should return from the forEach but it does not. Can someone help me in why this is not returning or a more optimised approach

Comment: Does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555904/foreach-for-in-not-returning-values .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [forEach/for...in not returning values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555904/foreach-for-in-not-returning-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go !

```js
var statusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: false},
  {label: '3', checked: false},
  {label: '4', checked: false},
  {label: '5', checked: false},
];

var activeStatusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: true},
  {label: '2', checked: true},
];
var set = new Set();
statusFilter.forEach(status =>  set.add(status.label));

activeStatusFilter =activeStatusFilter.filter(active => set.has(active.label));

console.log(activeStatusFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `Set`:

```js
const labels = new Set(statusFilter.map(v => v.label));
const filtered = activeStatusFilter.filter(v => labels.has(v.label));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output by a combinatino of `filter` and `find`

```
const z = activeStatusFilter.filter( activeStatus => {
  return statusFilter.find( s => activeStatus.label === s.label)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var statusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: false},
  {label: '3', checked: false},
  {label: '4', checked: false},
  {label: '5', checked: false},
];

var activeStatusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: true},
  {label: '2', checked: true},
];

const result = activeStatusFilter.filter(x => {
       return (statusFilter.findIndex( y => y.label === x.label) > -1)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var statusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: false},
  {label: '3', checked: false},
  {label: '4', checked: false},
  {label: '5', checked: false},
];

var activeStatusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: true},
  {label: '2', checked: true},
];
res=activeStatusFilter.filter(x=>statusFilter.some(y=>y.label==x.label))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. `filter()`
2. `some()`

an alternative approach to `Set`. Here is a working example:

```js
var statusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: false},
  {label: '3', checked: false},
  {label: '4', checked: false},
  {label: '5', checked: false},
];

var activeStatusFilter = [
  {label: '1', checked: true},
  {label: '2', checked: true},
];

var result = activeStatusFilter.filter(k=>statusFilter.some(l=>l.label==k.label));

console.log(result);
```