# End array map at an index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to only map an array up to a certain index?

For example, say I have the following:

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I want to sum up the numbers in the array, but only up to the 3rd index. Is it possible to pass in an argument to `Array.map()` to only go up to a given index? Or is this only possible using a `for` loop?

Comment: Why are you using map() to sum? reduce() would be better

Comment: For something as simple as your example, `nums[0]+nums[1]+nums[2]` would be my choice. For more complicated functions and bigger arrays (and sub-arrays), you might want to come up with your own function to do the iteration with a simple `for` loop to avoid copying and unnecessary iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say reduce :(

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of a forEach question which suggests to use break (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break). However, `VM1292:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement` will occur if that is used in map. I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```
nums.slice(0,3).map(...);
```

Comment: This is a fine way to proceed, but it should be noted that `.slice()` will create a new array and copy elements into it over the requested range. If the actual problem being solved involves a large original array and the actual range is also fairly large, this would be more expensive than using a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, map() is called on every element in the array. See the docs for details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). So, yes, you would need to use a different solution such as a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `slice()` to get array till a specific index

```
nums.slice(0,3).map();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `slice()` function  which returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```
nums.slice(0,3).map(//your code);
```

for more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice