# Break _.each loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to break _.each() loop? 
Tried with _.every(), it is looping through the data only once.

Sample code:

```
    _.each([1,2,3,4,5],function(num){ 
       if(num < 3)
          console.log(num)
       else{
          console.log(num);
          return false;
       }
   });
```

Output: 1 2 3 4 5

```
    _.every([1,2,3,4,5],function(num){ 
       if(num < 3)
          console.log(num)
       else{
          console.log(num);
          return false;
       }
   });
```

Output: 1 false

Comment: Really, you shouldn't use a foreach if you may need to return early. Just use a regular `for` in that case.

Comment: Sounds like you should just use Array's `some()`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Return whether or not all numbers are less than three, or...?

Comment: it's not nice to `break` things. Use `while`  instead.

Comment: Its just an sample code I have added. My project has different array data of html elements in which after specific condition it should return from the loop.

Comment: @smitachougale How about being more specific? The question smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: You'll want to explicitly `return true` from the `if` case in your `every` loop

Answer (score 2):

You cannot escape from the functional forEach loop.

Consider using a regular for loop instead.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    const num = arr[i];
    if(num < 3) {
       console.log(num)
    } else {
       console.log('break out');
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact you can.. 
`var break = false;
_.each([...],(num)=>{ 
   if(break) return
   [...]
   break = true;
});`

Comment: @Bellian it will still be in the loop though an then have an extra if check for break.....

Comment: Indeed i cant advise to do so but it is possible. Just for completion (didn't downvote btw..)

Comment: But again, that is not a loop break. Still looping ;-)

Comment: True. But does not perform :/

Comment: @Bellian If you want the ugly "solution" for breaking from a `each` callback "loop", use exceptions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641347/1048572) for details. But really, one should just not use `forEach` in that case.