# Break while loop in array.forEach inside it?

Tags: javascript

**Note:** I want to break the `while()` loop using the `forEach` callback function, not to break the `forEach` itself.

I'm currently trying to break a `while` loop in a forEach method inside that same while loop, but Javascript does not like `break` statements inside functions. It spits out `unsynctatic break` or `illegal break statement` depending on the environment.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
while(true) {
    example = [false, false, true];
    example.forEach(function breakWhile(element) {
        if(element) {break;}
    })
}
```

I'm aware that `for...of` (plus using a label on the `while` loop) solves this, but is it really my only way out? I quite prefer using `array.forEach`. And even worse, I could want to use a function instead, which is also underappreciated by JS engines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: @VoidRay not really, I want to break the while() loop, not the forEach.

Comment: There are [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) that you should use here, along with several other [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods.

Comment: @Rafael then you'll have to break it like any other while loop. running break in a callback certainly isn't the same as running it in the while loop. Your options are limited here. Breaking the forEach would be the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best option is just to use a flag.

```js
let dobreak = false;
while(!dobreak) {
    example = [false, false, true, false];
    example.forEach(function breakWhile(element) {
        if(element) {dobreak = true;}
        else if(!dobreak) {
          console.log(element);
        }
    })
}
```

Another idea is to create a function to replace the built-in forEach, here I've called it `breakForEach`  if you return true inside the iteration callback it will break the forEach, and also return true so you can break the while.

You could even add this to the default Array.prototype, but it's not advisable.

```js
function breakForEach(arr, iter) {
  for(let l = 0; l < arr.length; l ++) {
    if (iter(arr[l])) return true;    
  }
  return false;
}

while(true) {
    var example = [false, false, true, false];
    if (breakForEach(example, function breakWhile(element) {
        if(element) return true;
        console.log(element);
    })) break;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. That's not exactly what I wished (`break` is cleaner), but it is indeed a solution. Will wait a bit for a possible better solution before accepting this, but +1 for coming up with a solution at least. ;)

Comment: Is this a pattern you get regularly?  If so you could maybe create a helper function,. maybe called  `whileForEachBreak` or something like that.

Comment: Actually that's the first time I had to do this.

A helper function would be also less clean than just `break`ing with the forEach, but that doesn't seem to be a possibility.