# Cannot break for-loop: Unsyntactic break

Tags: javascript

I want to `break` a `for-loop` when a certain condition is met

```
Object.keys(s).map(uk => {
    Object.keys(s[uk]).map(ik => {
        for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (...) {
                s[uk][ik].map(elem => {
                    if (...) {
                        if (...) {
                            data.push(...);
                            break;
                            ...
```

However, the `break` statement gives me a

> Unsyntactic break

Why is that? Its only supposed to `break` the `for-loop`, or does `JavaScript` think that I want to break the `map`?

Comment: That is because `break` expects a loop. You are calling a function in loop. So break does not detects loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: @Rajesh I dont want to use `for-Each`. I am using a `for-loop`

Comment: why don't use `Array.some`

Comment: @Stophface The point of duplicate was, *how to break through a function*.

Comment: I must add that using multiple nested if conditions is a really bad practice...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like you yourself suggested, you are still in the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) part. That is actually an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and you are no longer in in the loop. Think of it as some function you defined elsewhere, but it's a quicker way of calling that function.

You are not using the map function as it is meant to be used in javascript. It isn't meant to be a convenient way to iterate over an array, but rather create a new array from some other array. You should change your usage of `map` to [some form of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Hm... So I would have to change all the `maps` into `for-loops`?

Comment: yes. i also added that in my answer, but the map function is not meant for iteration. it actually returns a new array and shouldn't be used for anything but that.

Comment: Would it work if I wrap the `map` inside the `for-loop`?

Comment: you are fighting the symptom, not the problem. the `map` function is not meant to be used to loop over the data. don't use it for that! if you are not storing the result of `map` in a variable you are not using it correctly

Comment: Hm, shouldnt make that much of a difference if I let the result of `map` disappear in the `void` I assume?!

Comment: there are two reasons why you shouldn't do it that way. first: blantly put this is more expensive on the hardware, as you create an arrow function expression and there is some array created in the background which gets readied for return. secondly: this is not best practice. There are always many ways to your goal in programming, but usually you'll write code in your professional life which get looked at and serviced by other people. using the "correct" way will make it easier for them to instantly understand your intuition and understand your code quicker.

Answer (score 15):

To fix this problem you can simply use
`return;` instead of `break;`

Answer (score 11):

You can't use `break` with methods like `map`, `reduce`, `forEach`, etc.
But you can `.filter` your data before or just `.find` the element you need