# Javascript For ... of loop in array not working in safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, safari

I've got a for..of javascript loop to loop through an array. My code snippet works fine in Chrome, IE & Firefox consoles without any problems but fails in the safari (version5.1.7) console. I get the following error:

```
line: 287
message: "Expected an identifier but found 'arr' instead"
sourceId: 2082538144
__proto__: Error
```

My code snippet is pretty simple and is as follows:

```
let arr = [11, 22, 34, 45, 66, 77, 88];

for(let elem of arr){
  console.log(elem);
  if(elem > 50){
    break;
  }
}
```

Has anyone else faced this issue and solved it?

Comment: Side note: Are you sure that it works in IE? Or are you testing on Edge?

Comment: Are you using any function here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MDN, [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) is supported from Safari 8 onwards.

So that might explain why it doesn't work with your Safari 5.

Comment: Update: I can't find a safari download for windows 10 that is higher than version 5

Comment: @RogerDodger hmm...it might be a good idea to try [`array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) then.

Comment: My go to usually is the forEach loop construct - but 'break' doesn't work in forEach, which is why I tried for...of which can handle a break statement.

Comment: @RogerDodger Yes, that's one of the limitations with `forEach`, but [there are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374/5894241) to work around that. Or, you can go with the `for` loop.