# How can I randomly get same data on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have user table and this code.

getOnline code and connected button

```
var onlineStatus = firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + "/online");
onlineStatus.set(1);
```

and

```
var dbUser = firebase.database();
var refUser = dbUser.ref("users");


refUser.orderByChild("online").equalTo(1).on("value", function(Data){
    console.log(Data.val(), Data.key);
});
```

I can  already see online=1 users, but I want to randomly get 1 user who has the online = 1.

How can I do this?

**Update**

I want to build randomly chat. people will match according to the criteria. like Tinder App. Think about it, there is a page and button. When the user presses the button, it will match any online user. and chatting.

firebase users;

```
users
     VIkvYAtLHxNqAwd722oKenriM7PJz2
        email: "mail@hotmail.com"
        online: 1 
        profile_picture:"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net" 
        username: "John Snow"

     DIkvYAtLHxNqAwd722oKenriM7PJz2
        email: "mail2@hotmail.com"
        online: 1 
        profile_picture:"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net" 
        username: "Jane Snow"
```

Comment: i'm newest , and I am trying to make a randomly matching chat with gifted-chat

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Math.random()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function to get a random number (let's call it **n**) and then get the **n**th user online:

```
refUser.orderByChild("online").equalTo(1).on("value", function(Data){
    console.log(Data.val(), Data.key);
    var totalOnline = Data.numChildren(); //get number of online users
    var randomNr = Math.random() * totalOnline;
    var userIndex = parseInt(randomNr, 10); //parse the random number from double to integer
    var currentIndex = 0;
    Data.forEach(function(snap){
        if(currentIndex==userIndex){
            var randomUser = snap.val();
            //Do something with your random user
            break;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    });
});
```

Also note that if you have a huge app with thousands of users, you might want to limit the query to 50 users to improve the app's performance:

```
refUser.orderByChild("online").equalTo(1).limitToFirst(50)
```

**Update**: To exclude your own user you can check if the random user is you. And if it is, go to the next one:

```
        if(currentIndex>=userIndex && snap.key != firebase.auth().currentUser.uid){
            var randomUser = snap.val();
            //Do something with your random user
            break;
        }
```

**Update 2:** I've discovered that you can't use `break` on `forEach` loop. So you can solve that using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374/5861618) (use a BreakException):

```
refUser.orderByChild("online").equalTo(1).on("value", function(Data){
    console.log(Data.val(), Data.key);
    var totalOnline = Data.numChildren(); //get number of online users
    var randomNr = Math.random() * totalOnline;
    var userIndex = parseInt(randomNr, 10); //parse the random number from double to integer
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var BreakException = {};
    try
    {
        Data.forEach(function(snap){
            if(currentIndex==userIndex){
                var randomUser = snap.val();
                //Do something with your random user
                throw BreakException;
            }
            currentIndex++;
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        if(e!== BreakException) throw e;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for help !!! :) and  i dont understand limitToFirst because i will matched filter " age , location and gender all users. example : i have a 1k user in same location . This code all check 1k user and work with limitToFirst(50) ?

Comment: this code worked but i matched own user . how can i exclude my own user ? because currentUser online = 1 too :/ thanks.

Comment: My bad @Cœur. The indices changed because I used the hyperlink button on the editor. I'll edit it manually next time. Thanks

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes oh, interesting, I wasn't aware of this side effect of using the editor. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes thanks for update but break; showing error so not working. and without break; code is working but all online = 1 users get :S

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes update comment : multiple users will match each other in this app. So 1 vs 1 will match. like Tinder App

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes hello again, I want to build randomly chat. people will match according to the criteria. like Tinder App. Think about it, there is a page and button. When the user presses the button, it will match any online user. and chatting. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: When i add break; error is " no message provided " .and when without break; i matched all online user. I need to match with 1 person. i used console.log(randomUser) @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: I need to match only 1 person online at that moment. all online users must match one random person. @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: HI @cnsvnc, how did you handle the multiple filtering on Firebase? For exmaple filter with age, location and gender?