# Why is this javascript function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, function

Why is this function returning undefined? It has a value inside the function, but once I try to assign it to a new variable, it comes back as undefined.

```
function getLookupDefault(lookupModel) {
    Object.keys(lookupModel.LookupValues).forEach(function (key) {
        if (lookupModel.LookupValues[key].IsDefault == true) {
            test = lookupModel.LookupValues[key].Name;
            console.log("test: " + test);
            return test;
        }
    })
};

var tst = getLookupDefault(model.LookupValuesDelimiter);
console.log("tst: " + tst);
```

Edit:
Thank you.  Coming from c#, this was not obvious to me.  I have edited the code to this and it works correctly.

```
function getLookupDefault(lookupModel) {
    for (var key in Object.keys(lookupModel.LookupValues)) {
        if (lookupModel.LookupValues[key].IsDefault == true) {
            test = lookupModel.LookupValues[key].Name;
            console.log("test: " + test);
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because it has no return statement in it - you also "return" in a .forEach callback, which is pointless, ... perhaps you wanted `map` instead

Comment: Where exactly have you declared the varible test?

Comment: @JaromandaX `return test;`

Comment: oh for goodness sake, remove the image, it adds nothing to the question

Comment: @ScottMarcus - yes, well spotted, but where is there a return in the `getLookupDefault` function? and returning a value from a forEach callback does nothing anyway

Comment: @ScottMarcus He uses it on the `forEach` block which is useless.

Comment: @JaromandaX You edited your comment. Your original comment made it seem like you didn't see any `return` in the code.

Comment: the edit does not change the first part of that comment ... `getLookupDefault` still has no return statement in it

Comment: I don't know if either of those duplicates is actually what OP is trying to do here. I think they're actually looking for a way to break out of a `forEach` loop with a `return` like you can do with a normal `for` loop in most languages.

Comment: If that is the case, [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101207/1112586) might be more like what they're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That return statement you have in there doesn't return a value to the outer function, it only returns a value to the inner function called by forEach.

Comment: i.e. it's a star trek GNDN ...  goes nowhere, does nothing