# React array map ,how to get only 2 objects from array.map

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {items: []}
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({results: items}) => this.setState({items}))
  }
  render() {
    let items = this.state.items
    return (
      <div>

      <ul>
      {items.map((item) =>
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
        </li>

      )}
    </ul>


      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

- Here the Array.map render all the properties from object.

  I want only 2 objects using array.map method and render only 2 objects, not all

  how can I do this ?

  Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a slice in render: `items.slice(0, 2).map(...)` or in the API call if you don't need to keep it in state: `this.setState({ items: items.slice(0, 2) })`.

Use `slice(-2)` if you want the last 2 items instead.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break). The map (and forEach as in the link) don't have a way to `break` out of them since this is not how they're intended to be used.

However you can avoid returning anything after certain criteria:

```
<ul>
  {items.map((item, index) =>
    {
     return nothing, hence render nothing if more than 2 items.
     if(index >= 2) return null;

    return(
    <li key={item.id}>
      {item.name}
    </li>);
    }
  )}
</ul>
```

However, this is also an unclean solution.

A better way is to get a new variable with only the values you want to map though. Since you're already doing `let items = this.state.items`, you might as well `let items = this.state.items.slice(0,2)` to get only the first 2 elements and map through them using your normal map in your render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) option for filtering the elements from an array or use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.