# Break the loop of an Array looping function (map, forEach, etc.)

Tags: javascript, control-structure

How can I break (similar to the `break` statement) from an implicit loop on an array?

The `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.forEach`, etc. functions imply a loop over the elements of the array. I want to conditionally break that loop early.

This contrived example:

```js
const colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];

colours.map(item => {
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        break;
    }
});
```

causes a `SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch`.

How can I break the loop the same way a `break` statement would?

Comment: `Array#map` is not designed for iteration with side effects (and must not be used for that purpose), it cannot be stopped. `Array#forEach` cannot be stopped either though. If you need to find something you need to use `Array#indexOf` or `Array#find` or any other lookup method.

Comment: You can't break a map. You'll have to use a stoppable method, such as `for` or `while` or, as @zerkms suggested, you could search for your item without iterating at all.

Comment: You can't because those methods don't allow for it. But, if you really need that functionality, you should just use a `for` loop with a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#map`, `Array#forEach` and so on have never been designed to be stopped. That would feel odd since the intent of `map` as well `forEach` really is to iterate over all items.

Also i don't think it is possible to notify the caller that a `break` event has occurred, since it is within a function that is not an integral part of the original loop.

So let's see at a custom method that stops the loop at the first occurrence of `true` without returning the matching value itself:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'untilTrue', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(lambda) { 
     for(let i in this) {
       if(lambda.call(this, this[i])) return;
      }
    }
});

const colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];

colours.untilTrue(item => {
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        return true;
    }
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comparing this custom `untilTrue` to the use of `Array#find`:

```js
const colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];

colours.find(item => {
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The only notable difference is that `untilTrue` doesn't return the matching item - `Array#find` does that in addition to call `lambda`.

So in general i would just stick to `Array#find` to keep the code neat and clean and use it like this:

```js
const colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];

if(colours.find(item => item.startsWith("y")) !== undefined) {
  console.log("The yessiest colour!");
}
```

This stops the loop at the first match (and returns the matching element). Also note that you have to compare against `undefined` - in case you were searching for a `false` or `null` value, the check would never evaluate to `true` if just compared to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it using a regular way. You can emulate the `break` behaviour by remembering whether the loop is "broken". The lack of this solution is that the loop actually continues (though the iteration logic is skipped).

```
let isBroken = false;

colours.map(item => {
    if (isBroken) {
        return;
    }
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        isBroken = true;
        return;
    }
});
```

The best solution for your example is to use a plain `for` loop.

```
for (colour of colours) {
    if (colour.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Also you can use a dirty way to actually stop a `map` loop.

```
colours.map((item, index, array) => {
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        array.splice(0, index);
    }
});
// The colours array will be modified after this loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Although `forEach` is designed to run some function that *doesn't* change the array (i.e. it is designed to do some other side effect for each item), it is explicitly documented to have no way of breaking the loop.

From the [MDN documentation for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the `forEach()` method is the wrong tool.

So, despite `forEach` being designed for side-effects, there is no normal access to the control structure of the loop.

Because `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` are intended to generate a new value, they are not designed for side effects like breaking early. The documentation doesn't appear to say that explicitly.

---

Possible alternatives to try: re-write the code to use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). These are explicitly documented to terminate the loop early when their condition is known (when `some` would return `true`, or when `every` would return `false`).

```js
const colours = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];

colours.some(item => {
    if (item.startsWith("y")) {
        console.log("The yessiest colour!");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"`forEach` being designed for side-effects"*?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. It's correct and it explains why very well.

Comment: @Scott, basically because the question was asked without research and when OP finally researched decided to answer their own question with what they should have read before asking.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, answering one's own question is a valid way of using StackExchange sites. I had this problem, and wanted to document the answer once I found it.

Comment: I personally won't. Duplicating MDN content on StackOverflow won't get my thumb up. Here's [my opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on the subject. And by the way, what you linked is not "documentation for `forEach`". [This one](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) is.

Comment: Also, `Array#reduce` is not intended to generate a new array - it can be used for that, but not exclusively and in most of such cases `Array#map`, `Array#filter` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

you can throw an exception if your only option is to use Array.forEach

Refer this:

[How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

There are other methods available which can solve your purpose too. For example you can use method: Array.prototype.some() if you want to check some condition and break the loop based on that condition.

Example can be referenced here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom forEach method in these ways

```
Array.prototype._forEach = function (callback) {
  let _break = false;

  const breaker = () => {
    _break = true;
  };

  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
    if (_break) break;

    callback(this[index], index, breaker);
  }
};


// Example for usage:

const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

letters._forEach((data, index, breaker) => {
  if (data === "c") return; // continue role

  if (data === "e") return breaker(); // break role

  console.log(`log ${index}:  ${data}`);
});

/**
 * result:
 *  log 0:  a
 *  log 1:  b
 *  log 3:  d
 */
```

or you can create top custom forEach method by creating

```
function forEach(items, callback) {
  let _break = false;

  const breaker = () => {
    _break = true;
  };

  for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    if (_break) break;

    callback(items[index], index, breaker);
  }
}
```