# Break the foreach method when the value comes true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I have to break the forEach method when the value of available is true.

```
[
  {
    "Book": "Book1",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book2",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book3",
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book4",
    "available": true
  }
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwJqq.png)

And print only one item after the value of available comes true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: No, I have to print only one item after the value comes true.

Comment: It is not clear to me why the code in the image would give an error. And please don't post code as a screenshot, let alone a *link* to a screenshot. We need more context of the code around. It's not really a run-time error happening here; it's a syntax error, which we can't figure out without seeing more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEach doesn't support break. use `for of`

```
for (const el of arr) {
   if (el.available) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: When I am using the for of in react js it gives the error.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Expression expected.

Comment: did you include the if condition? which line is the error?

Comment: I am new on Stackoverflow, Is there any option to send the picture

Comment: update the original question

Comment: Please see the image on the original question I have added the image with an error.

Comment: calling inside the template requires returning a value to render in DOM. move the for loop to a function and return an element or string from that function to

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `forEach` will run on all values in the array. There is a loop under the hood, but you don't have control over the loop body.

If you want to break at some position in the loop, just use a for-of loop:

```js
for (const book of books) {
    if (book.available) break;
}
```

Comment: When I am using the for of in react js it gives the error

Comment: You should add _how_ you're using the code by adding that code to the question (as a [mcve]). Most likely you'll have to shift that code to its own function and then call it from the JSX. @DipeshKumarSah

Answer (score 0):

You can't break the `forEach`.

If you want to print only one item. I think the `find` method is what you are looking for.

```js
const list = [
  {
    "Book": "Book1",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book2",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book3",
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book4",
    "available": true
  }
] 

const item = list.find(({available})=>available)
// item would be  {
//    "Book": "Book3",
//    "available": true
//  }
```

For more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

[`find` will short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the iteration after it finds the first instance where the condition is met. You may want to put that code in its own function and then call it from the JSX.

Note I've relabeled the `Book` property to `title` here as it made a little more sense semantically.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {
  
  // Get the first available book, and
  // return its title
  function findFirst(data) {
    return data.find(book => {
      return book.available;
    }).title;
  }
  
  // Call the function
  return (
    <div>
      {findFirst(data)}
    </div>
  );

}

const data=[{title:"Book1",available:!1},{title:"Book2",available:!1},{title:"Book3",available:!0},{title:"Book4",available:!0}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue earlier. I found that it is not possible to declare break in forEach or in map function. It will traverse the whole array instead. You can use break in for loop. However using a flag it can be done.

Reference:
[Past Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558227/break-the-loop-of-an-array-looping-function-map-foreach-etc)

MDN article: [MDN article on ForEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

However for loop will do that easily.
Such as:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "Book": "Book1",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book2",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book3",
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book4",
    "available": true
  }
]

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].available){
    console.log(data[i]);
    break;
  }
}
```

This will give you the very first available which is true only. However you can also use find function to do get the same output:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "Book": "Book1",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book2",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book3",
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book4",
    "available": true
  }
]

let findData = data.find(item => {
  if(item.available){
    return item;
  }
  return false;
});
console.log(findData);
```