# How to break ForEach Loop in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach, break

I have a the below code, on which i am unable to break the loop on certain conditions.

```
function isVoteTally(): boolean {
  let count = false;
  this.tab.committee.ratings.forEach((element) => {
    const _fo = this.isEmptyOrNull(element.ratings.finalOutcome.finaloutlook);
    const _foreign = this.isEmptyOrNull(element.ratings.finalOutcome.foreign);
    const _local = this.isEmptyOrNull(element.ratings.finalOutcome.local);
    const _tally =
      element.ratings.finalOutcome.voteTally.maj +
      element.ratings.finalOutcome.voteTally.dis;

    if (_fo == false && _foreign == false && _local == false) {
      if (_tally > 0) {
        return (count = false); // ⭐
      }
    } else {
      if (_tally < 0) {
        return (count = false); // ⭐
      }
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

On the star-marked areas, I want to *break* the code and return the boolean value, but I am unable to do. How can it be done?

Comment: The MDN is a great resource on JavaScript and the types/methods available. Here's the page on [Array.ForEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). And it has a section specifically about alternatives you can use if you need to break. "Early termination may be accomplished with:"

Comment: Please update the best answer to that provided by @Roberc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: Also the question should be renamed to: How to break ForEach Loop by returning a value in TypeScript. At the moment the title is a little bit misleading because you can break forEach loop by returning nothing.

Comment: The comment from @user310988 has been the best answer I've seen throughout dozens of minutes of searching.  Roberc's answer only solves for one case so that should not be the accepted answer.  In an ocean of incorrect/incomplete answers, I finally find the proper one.

Comment: This is crying for a [mre]. I'm not editing to turn it into one because I'm not sure if it's in my place to do so.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is not possible to break from `forEach()` normally.

Alternatively you can use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) because you wish to return `false` while breaking the loop.

If you want to return true, then you can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
this.tab.committee.ratings.every(element => {

  const _fo = this.isEmptyOrNull(element.ratings.finalOutcome.finaloutlook);
  const _foreign = this.isEmptyOrNull(element.ratings.finalOutcome.foreign);
  const _local = this.isEmptyOrNull(element.ratings.finalOutcome.local);
  const _tally = element.ratings.finalOutcome.voteTally.maj + element.ratings.finalOutcome.voteTally.dis;

  if (_fo == false && _foreign == false && _local == false) {
    if (_tally > 0) {
      **return count = false;**
    }
  } else {
    if (_tally < 0) {
      **return count = false;**
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 158):

`this.tab.committee.ratings.forEach` is not an operator.

Typescript allows for much more readable code.

Use a `for` loop in style as follows:

```
for (let a of this.tab.committee.ratings) {
   if (something_wrong) break;
}
```

p.s. forget "coding as with jQuery" in Angular. It just doesn't work.

Comment: I am not able to find documentation for `of`.

Comment: @Mangesh this syntax is not Angular-specific. It's new ECMAScript standard. You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: For large arrays, this is more performant since it breaks upon first match, and does not need to go through every element.

Comment: @Mangesh: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#forof-vs-forin-statements

Comment: Nice! Better that `.forEach` for my taste. Even if that's not directly answering question.

Comment: Just to add, always prefer using `const` over `let`. You won't want to attribute a new value to `a` here.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot ‘break’, it won’t even run because the break instruction is not technically in a loop.
Solution?
Just use a normal for loop. Nobody would laugh at you.

Answer (score 3):

I think even better solution is to use for.
With for you can return a value when it's found and break the loop. It's a lot cleaner solution

```
for (element of this.tab.committee.ratings) {
// and here you use your element, when you return a values it stops the cycle

if (element === something){
 return element;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a local variable

```
function() {
var itemFound=false;
  arr.forEach((item:any) => {
    if(item === '2' && !itemFound) {
      itemFound = true;
    }
  });  
 return itemFound;
}
```

Comment: In this case, why not just use `find`? `return !!arr.find(item => item === ‘2’);`

Answer (score -3):

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
var breakMe = false;

blocks.forEach((block, i) => {
    if(breakMe == false) {
        /*code that you want*/ 
        if(i < 2) {
            block.style.background = 'red';
        } else if(i != 4) {
            block.style.background = 'blue';
        } else if(i == 4) {
            breakMe = true;
            /*change breackMe to true if you want to breack forEach*/
        }
    }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="block" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: purple; margin: 50px"></div>      
      <div class="block" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: purple; margin: 50px"></div>
      <div class="block" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: purple; margin: 50px"></div>
      <div class="block" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: purple; margin: 50px"></div>
      <div class="block" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: purple; margin: 50px"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can break foreach loop by using try-catch statement

```
try {
  arr.forEach((item:any) => {
    if(item === '2') {
      throw "break";
    }
    console.log('Item ID: ', item);
  });  
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Warn Error',e);
}
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions to brake loop, too expensive and purpose of exceptions is not that. Just use a regular for... loop, or arr.find() per example.

Answer (score -22):

simply do `return false;`. It will break.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach "There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool."