# Javascript function returns true when it should return false

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks if a param exists in an array of inputs. It should return false but does not.

```
{
  ...
  validation: params => {
    const valid = ["valid", "inputs"];
    valid.forEach( v=> {
      if (!params.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
        return false;
      }
    });

    return true;
  }
```

So even when the if statement does evaluate to be true it never return false. This function always returns true no matter what.

Comment: Because the `return false` stmt is of you callback's return stmt.try setting a boolean in callback and return on basic of that or use for loop instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: If someone can post how I could refactor this code to work the way I intend I can accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative, use the right tool for the job. If you want to check whether every member of an array has a certain property, use `every`:

```
validation: params => {
  const valid = ["valid", "inputs"];
  return valid.every(v => params.hasOwnProperty(v));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's really a better idea.

Answer (score 4):

You're `return` is returning from the callback function of `forEach` not the main function. You can't return early from a `forEach` without something like a `throw`. If you want to return early use a `for...of` loop instead:

```
validation: params => {
    const valid = ["valid", "inputs"];
    for (v of valid) {
      if (!params.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
      return false;  // this returns from the main function
    }
  };

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Callbacks are a pain in the arse.