# How to stop for loop if response from api is false?

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop, angular5

How do I stop for loop if response comes false from the api?. I have below code for api integration. Now currently api is calling as per loop at one time. I want to do call the same api if response from the api is true. Below is my code

```
            for (let i = 0; i < this.fooditemselecteddetails.length; i++) {                   
                this.spinnerService.hide();     
                //console.log(this.fooditemselecteddetails);                          
                this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/AddConcessions?CinemaId=' + this.cinemaid + '&TransactionId=' + this.temptransaction.TransactionId + '&ItemId=' + this.fooditemselecteddetails[i].id + '&Quantity=' + this.fooditemselecteddetails[i].quantity + "&BookingId=" + this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID, '').subscribe((result: any) => {

                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                    this.addconcession = result;
                    console.log(this.addconcession);


                    if (this.addconcession.IsSuccess == true) {
                        if (i == this.fooditemselecteddetails.length - 1) {
                            localStorage.setItem("bookingid", this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID);
                            this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/FinalBookingDetails?BookingId=' + this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID, '').subscribe((result2: any) => {
                                this.vistavalidation = result2;
                                if (this.vistavalidation.BookingID > 0) {
                                    this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/ContinueTransaction?CinemaId=' + this.cinemaid + '&TransactionId=' + this.temptransaction.TransactionId, '').subscribe((result3: any) => {
                                        if (result3.IsSuccess) {
                                            this.ContinueTransactionresult = result3;
                                            this.showTabOnClick('tabs-4');
                                        }
                                        else {                                           
                                            this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", result3.Error, "info");
                                            this.spinnerService.hide();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else {

                                    this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", 'something went wrong, please try again', "info");
                                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", result.Error, "error");
                        this.spinnerService.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
```

I want to call `AddConcessions?` this api again if response from this api is true. If it's returns false then stop loop there only.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to run your service in Synchronous fashion.

Here is the change you can make to execute your code in sequence

```
addConcessions(i) {
   this.spinnerService.hide();     
                //console.log(this.fooditemselecteddetails);                          
                this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/AddConcessions?CinemaId=' + this.cinemaid + '&TransactionId=' + this.temptransaction.TransactionId + '&ItemId=' + this.fooditemselecteddetails[i].id + '&Quantity=' + this.fooditemselecteddetails[i].quantity + "&BookingId=" + this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID, '').subscribe((result: any) => {

                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                    this.addconcession = result;
                    console.log(this.addconcession);


                    if (this.addconcession.IsSuccess == true) {
                        if (i == this.fooditemselecteddetails.length - 1) {
                            localStorage.setItem("bookingid", this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID);
                            this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/FinalBookingDetails?BookingId=' + this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID, '').subscribe((result2: any) => {
                                this.vistavalidation = result2;
                                if (this.vistavalidation.BookingID > 0) {
                                    this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/ContinueTransaction?CinemaId=' + this.cinemaid + '&TransactionId=' + this.temptransaction.TransactionId, '').subscribe((result3: any) => {
                                        if (result3.IsSuccess) {
                                            this.ContinueTransactionresult = result3;
                                            this.showTabOnClick('tabs-4'); 
                                            index--;
                                            if(index >= 0){
                                              this.addConcessions(index);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {                                           
                                            this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", result3.Error, "info");
                                            this.spinnerService.hide();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else {

                                    this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", 'something went wrong, please try again', "info");
                                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", result.Error, "error");
                        this.spinnerService.hide();
                    }
                });

   }
```

> call this function as

```
this.addConcessions(this.fooditemselecteddetails.length-1);
```

Comment: I did'nt get it. Can you please explain?. I'm new to backend

Comment: I understand there loop in another function. So you can remove the loop and put this call this function `addConcessions` as mentioned. It will make the recursive call until the error occurred or all items are completed

Comment: So you mean make addConcessions(index) as another function and that function will call on place of for loop. rigtht?

Comment: Exactly, you got it.

Comment: Did it but it giving i is undefined

Comment: Change `addConcessions(index)`  to `addConcessions(i) `

Comment: Updated your question with changes so that we can figure out what is the issue now.

Comment: Call this way `this.addConcessions(this.fooditemselecteddetails.length-1);`

Comment: Can you please explain? I want to understand what you have done

Comment: Its recursive call of function `addConcessions`. It will call itself with next value if the current API is passed.

Comment: Great. Thank you, will see this topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182248/discussion-between-sagar-kodte-and-sunil-singh).