# How to loop over an enmap

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to loop through an enmap, but it doesn't seem to be working. I got `forEach()` to work, however, I need to be able to break out of it, which doesn't work with `forEach()`. Here's what I currently have

```
for(var id in bot.myenmap.fetchEverything()) {
  console.log("test")
}
```

I have no other details as I can provide, as it doesn't error or log anything. If you know how to loop over it, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you tried `of` not `in`

Comment: No, I will though.

Comment: `in` is used to loop the properties of an object, `of` is the collection iterator.

Comment: I never knew that, it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Most welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you got `forEach()` to work, you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374/7133466): it explains how to "break" out of a `forEach()` loop.
You have to put the loop inside a `try` block, when you want to break the loop you can throw a custom exception: in the `catch` statement you'll make it ignore your custom exceptions, while throwing the ones that you didn't plan (like it normally would). Here's an example:

```
// This is to declare the custom exception:
var BreakException = {};

try {
  bot.myenmap.forEach((element) => {
    // This is like a normal forEach loop
    // When you want to break it, just do this:
    throw BreakException;
  });
} catch (e) {
  // If it's a BreakException it will ignore it and not givce errors
  if (e !== BreakException) throw e;
}
```

Code adapted from the answer mentioned above.