# JavaScript: Use forEach to see if array contains a specific number value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input, element

I have the code below. I am purposefully trying to use forEach in this instance.

```
function check(arr, el) {

  arr.forEach((element) => {

    console.log(element)

    if (element === el) {

       return true
    }
  })
}

check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
```

I am expecting the code to return true because the el value of 3 is in the array.  But instead it returns undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `return` in the `forEach`. Store the match and then return at the end.

Comment: You are using the wrong method, forEach does not return.... ALl it does is exit that iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot use `return` inside a `forEach` statement.

NOTE: This answer is **only** because you need to use `forEach`.
Ordinarily you would always use `some()`.

```js
function check(arr, el) {
  let found = false;
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element)
    if (element === el) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;
}



console.log( check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
```

Answer (score 5):

[**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) don't [**return**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) anything ( means undefined ), you can use [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
function check(arr, el) {
  return arr.some( element => element === el)
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

If you want to use `forEach` than use a variable to store value and than return later from function

```js
function check(arr, el) {
  let found = false
  
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    if (element === el && !found){
      found = true
    }
  })
  return found
}



console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to use OP's context. since one has to use forEach.

```
function check(arr, el) {

  let found = false;

  arr.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element)
    if (element === el){
        found = true;
    }
  })

  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `forEach` you need to have a variable being updated when you find a match. [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) by default returns `undefined`. There is no `build in` way to [break out of the forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break).

Since you are just looking for a simple element match simply use `Array.includes`:

```js
let check = (arr, el) => arr.includes(el)

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

[Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) gives you an iterator function which in this case you really do not need.

With `Array.forEach`:

```js
function check(arr, el) {
  let result = false
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    if (element === el) {
      result = true  // <-- update the result on match
    }
  })
  return result  // <-- return the result
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

Comment: curiosity question: why can't you return from forEach?

Comment: Added a link with more information as well in regards to breaking out of the forEach etc.