# continue outside of loop statement (in some())

Tags: javascript

```
something.some((test) => {
    if(a == 0) {
        if(b == 0) {
            continue;
        }
    }
});
```

Can I skip one loop with this `continue`?

The WebStorm reports `continue outside of loop statement`.

Comment: `continue` is only for traditional `for` and `while` loops.

Comment: No, you cannot. `some` is not a loop construct, but a method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `continue`, but you can use `return` to skip the rest of the statements in your handler and continue with the next item:

```
something.some((test) => {
    if(a == 0) {
        if(b == 0) {
            return;
        }
        // X...
    }
    // Y...
});
```

If the logic hits the `return` for an entry, then neither the code at `X` or `Y` above will be executed for that entry.

If you want the equivalent of `break` (stop the "loop" entirely) within a `some` callback, return `true`.

---

Side note: That usage of `some` looks suspect. Normally, you only use `some` if you return a value from the `some` callback (telling `some` whether to continue). Probably 90% *(waves hands)* of the time you also use `some`'s return value to know whether the loop was stopped early or continued. If you never return anything from the callback, `forEach` (or a `for-of` loop) would be the idiomatic choice, not `some`.