# how to return true on the external function

Tags: javascript, return

how to conditionally check &return `true` from `forEach` function for an example like below? Thanks!

```
this.results.forEach(el => {
  el.forEach(el => {
    if (el == 3) {
      //return true here is not working  
    }
  })
});

if (this.SlantLeft == 3 || this.SlantRight == 3) {
  return true //like this
}
```

Comment: do you have some data to test and the wanted result?

Comment: You can't, forEach ignores the return value of its callbacks. Maybe you want .find instead?

Comment: Use [`for...of`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101207/3082296) with return or use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Okay thanks it's fine but when I'm working on one array, how to do this when i have arrays in array?

Comment: You add nested `for...of` like you have nested forEach. `for (let el of this.results) for (let n of el) if(n === 3) return true` (You have named both the forEach callback's parameter as `el`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `some()`, which will return true if any of the iterable elements meets a condition, otherwise false.

```
this.results.some(el => el == 3);
```