# How to break out of a JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

this is my function and I want to break the loo when the condition is met, but I'm getting an error:

> SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Im using protractor with javascript.

```js
async CompareTableData(byElement, param) {
  try {
    await this.WaitToBeClickable(element(By.cssContainingText(byElement.value, param)));
    await element.all(byElement).then(async function(item) {
      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        item[i].getText().then(async function(text) {
          var trimTxt = text.trim();
          if (await trimTxt == param && byElement.using == "css selector") {
            console.log(`Param FOUND! ${param}\n`);
            await expect(element(By.cssContainingText(byElement.value, param)).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            break;
          } else {
            return;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Table comparison FAILED, element not present!");
    return console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: you're not _in_ a for loop, you're in an async function. If you want to return early, just `return`. However, a `return` makes no sense here, because you're inside an if/else: `if (a) { return x; } else { return y; }` is the same as `if (a) { return x; } return y` (no need for an else, by definition if you're still here, we haven't returned yet). And then on top of that, a `return` without any argument is what functions already do, so there's literally no reason for this code. Just use `if (...) { await ...; }` without any returns, and without an `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointer out your break is not in your loop but instead in an anonymous function in your `.then`. Other than that the main issue is that you are not handling your promises well. `Async/await` was introduced to make handling promises easier by not requiring you to use `.then` statements so you should definitely not be using them together in this way.

Also `expect` statements are synchronous so do not require an await but the actions within the expect will (almost always) be async when using Protractor so that statement should read `expect(await element(By.cssContainingText(byElement.value, param)).isPresent()).toBe(true);`

You can rewrite you code like so:

```
async function CompareTableData(byElement, param) {
    try {
        await this.WaitToBeClickable(element(By.cssContainingText(byElement.value, param)));
        const item = await element.all(byElement)

        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            const text = await item[i].getText();
            var trimTxt = text.trim();
            if (trimTxt == param && byElement.using == "css selector") {
                console.log(`Param FOUND! ${param}\n`);
                expect(await element(By.cssContainingText(byElement.value, param)).isPresent()).toBe(true);
                break;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Table comparison FAILED, element not present!");
        return console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank YOU! very much! I'm new to JS so this helps a lot to understand the async functions! again! THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem @Alan, happy to help. If this answer did resolve your issue would you mind accepting this answer so that other users in future may see it solved.