# How to check if all elements with same class name all have the same style property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

How do you check if a set of elements (7 total), that all have the same class name, all have the `display` property set to `none`, using Javascript? If all those `display` properties are set to `none` then set the button `disable = false`. If any of those elements, even just one, have `display` equal to `block`, set the button `disable = true`. Below is the failing attempt:

```
const errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".invalid-password")
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#account_submit")
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    errorMessages.forEach(message => {
        if (message.style.display !== "none") {
            submitButton.disabled = true;
        } else {
            submitButton.disabled = false;
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `break` from the loop if one of the elements is appearing. However, there is no built-in function to break from the `foreach` loop in `JavaScript`, so, you can use this method in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break):

```js
const errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".invalid-password")
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#account_submit")

try {

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    errorMessages.forEach(message => {
        console.log(message.style.display)
        if (message.style.display !== "none") {
            submitButton.disabled = true;
            throw BreakException;
        } else {
            submitButton.disabled = false;
        }
    })
})

} catch(e) { if (e !== BreakException) throw e; }
```

```html
<button id="account_submit">Click</button>

<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:block">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
```

A better way would be to define a function to check this condition and use it on `click`:

```js
const errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".invalid-password")
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#account_submit")

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    submitButton.disabled = checkVisibility();
})

function checkVisibility(){
  for(let i = 0; i < errorMessages.length; i++){
        if (errorMessages[i].style.display !== "none") {
            return true;
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

```html
<button id="account_submit">Click</button>

<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:block">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
<h6 class="invalid-password" style="display:none">test</h6>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since ECMAScript 2015 (ES 6) you could use `Array.from` and `Array.some`:

```
const disableButton =  Array.from(errorMessages).some(({style}) => style.display !== "none"));
submitButton.disabled = disableButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use inline style to hide divs, their *style.display* property will be empty, so the best bet is to test if any of them has `style.display == 'block'` to disable submit button and it's not a good idea to do these checks inside button click event, because it could be disabled and you won't have a chance to enable it again.

Show or hide your divs when you validate the forms and do the checks to enable or disable the submit button:

```js
const errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".invalid-password");
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#account_submit");
const field1 = document.querySelector("#field1");
function checkMessages() {
    submitButton.disabled = false;
    errorMessages.forEach(message => {
        if(message.style.display == 'block') {
            submitButton.disabled = true;
            return;
        }
    });
}
field1.addEventListener("input", function() {
    if(this.value == '') {
        errorMessages[0].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        errorMessages[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    checkMessages();
});
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Enabled');
})
```

```css
.invalid-password {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="field1" type="text" value="">
<div class="invalid-password">1</div>
<div class="invalid-password">2</div>
<div class="invalid-password">3</div>
<div class="invalid-password">4</div>
<div class="invalid-password">5</div>
<div class="invalid-password">6</div>
<input type="submit" id="account_submit" value="Submit" disabled="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient method but another way to approach this is to define a variable equal to 0 and for each message, if the display is none increment the variable by 1. Then check if the variable = 7 (which means all 7 elements were display: none) to toggle the disabled.

```js
const errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".invalid-password");
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#account_submit");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let disabled = 0;
    errorMessages.forEach(message => {
        if (message.style.display !== "none") {
           disabled++;
        }
        
        if (disabled === 7) {
          submitButton.disabled = true;
        } else {
          submitButton.disabled = false;
        }
    })
  console.log(disabled);
})
```

```css
.invalid-password {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<button id="account_submit">Submit</button>

<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password1</p>
<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password2</p>
<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password3</p>
<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password4</p>
<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password5</p>
<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password6</p>
<p class="invalid-password">Invalid password7</p>
```