# jQuery loop vs vanilla JS loop: break/continue/return

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

From my experience, if you want to exit a jQuery each loop you need to use `return true` or `return false` to continue or break respectfully.

```
$.each([1,2,3,4], function( index, value ) {
  if (value == 1) {
    // This will make us jump to the next value (continue)
    return true; 
  } else {
    //This will make us exit the loop (break)
    return false; 
  }
  console.log('This will never print');
});
```

But in vanilla JS you can use directly `continue` and `break`, and you can use `return` to exit the function all together.

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    // This will make us jump to the next value
    continue; 
  } else {
    //This will make us exit the loop
    break; 
  }
  console.log('This will never print');
}
```

Why is that?

And also, can you exit a jQuery loop by returning immediately, without having to pass a value to a local variable?

---

NOTE

Has a frequent user (although not much of a giver back) I really didn't enjoy having my question marked as duplicated, since my question is not the same as the one suggested by *Ryan Wilson* and *David*.

My question is more to the core of WHY it has that behaviour and not so much as to HOW to solve it.

Comment: `continue` and `break` work only in normal loops, whereas `.each` is a *method call* where you supply *a callback function*, so you're not in the context of an actual loop structure. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break) goes into the details of the vanilla JS `.forEach` but it's applicable for the jQuery `.each` as well.

Comment: Please show examples of these loops you're talking about. Note that the source code for jQuery is available on their GitHub site. For instance, [the source for `jQuery.each`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b502866960b30863e56968bd35e720905ac58025/src/core.js#L238)

Comment: @VLAZ Except you can't break out of `.forEach` :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's true. Small difference to jQuery. Still understanding how the iteration methods work will ultimately make the jQuery iteration methods trivial to reason for as well.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for the answer. I understand the reason now (and I also understand my question was a bit lazy). Looking at the source code really did it for me.