# Why am I getting empty file from pipe when tried multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
router.get('/excel', (req, res) => {
    Person.find()
        .then((result) => {
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("file.xls");
            const header = "Name" + "\t" + " Age" + "\n";
            writeStream.write(header);
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                const row = result[i].name + "\t" + result[i].age + "\n";
                writeStream.write(row);
            }
            writeStream.close();
        }).then(() => {
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.xls');
            var filestream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../file.xls');
            filestream.pipe(res);
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send(err);
        });
});
```

I have this code block to write an xls file and download it from client end. Though it gives the file with content first one or two times, thereafter it gives an empty xls file.
Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: It seems like you are not calling destroy, meaning you are missing the parentheses. So it should become filestream.destroy().

Comment: Sorry I put it by a mistake.  It didn't make any difference.

Comment: [How to wait for loop of stream.write() to end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64908368/4321299)

Comment: When tried only with header without the loop, result is the same.

Comment: use `fs.writeFileSync` instead of `fs.createWriteStream` to write the file like in the suggested answer

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Is it possible to get the output using  `fs.createWriteStream` as above code?