# Why node.js Array.prototype.forEach() loop don't pass values or objects to function return in the middle of loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why node.js Array.prototype.forEach() loop don't pass values or objects to function return in the middle of loop?

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function loop_n_return(char){
    array1.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element);
        if(element === char){
            return element;
        }
    });
}

loop_n_return('b'); //output: unidentified
```

but this works:

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function loop_n_return(char){
    var found_element;
    array1.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element);
        if(element === char){
            found_element = element;
        }
    });
    return found_element;
}

loop_n_return('b'); //output: b
```

Comment: You are returning the `element` inside the `callback` function. This is another function that is not responsible to return something from `loo_n_return` function.

Comment: Anything returned from the callback function DOES NOT automatically becomes a return value of the outer function. Also, `forEach` method does not return anything, so its useless to return anything from its callback function. Looking at your code, you probably should use `find` method. With this method, code inside your function could be reduced to just one line: `return array1.find(el => el === char)`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Comment: See [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](/q/34653612/4642212).

Comment: Many thanks to all.  Actually what I was doing was creating a variable inside the loop assign the value of the element and the return( it also inside the same loop instance) Even so the problem was the same since is was just an abstraction of the same exact thing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), not `.forEach()`.

```
const foundElement = array1.find( element => {
   console.log(element)
   return element === char // true if match
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning a value in the forEach callback won't change the return value of the function `loop_n_return`.

If you use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop howver, you can return the value as soon as it's found, this would also be more efficient, since you won't loop through every single value in the array.

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function loop_n_return(arr, char){
    for(let element of arr) {
        if (element === char) {
            return element;
        }
    }
}

console.log(loop_n_return(array1, 'a'));
console.log(loop_n_return(array1, 'b'));
console.log(loop_n_return(array1, 'c'));
```